# Names for reference image files

Tags: graphics

Is there anything I can do so that the PNG file name can have space and "ç"?

```
\documentclass[11pt,fleqn]{book}

\usepackage[top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=3cm,right=3cm,headsep=10pt,a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[]{titlesec}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

    \section{Aba Esboço}

%Minitable
    \tcbsidebyside[title=Aba esboço,
    sidebyside adapt=left,
    bicolor,colback=white,colbacklower=yellow!10,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,center title,drop lifted shadow,
    ]{%
    \includegraphics[height=4cm]{Aba esboço.png}
    %
    }{%
    Texto aqui.
    }
%

\end{document}
```

[image]

I only get some results using: aba_esboco.png

[image]

Result:

[image]

**Aba esboço.png**

[image]

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8422/how-to-include-graphics-with-spaces-in-their-path/8426#8426