# Remove the path that accompannies a EPS file at TeX

Tags: pdftex, texmaker, eps

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=3.0in]{C:/Users/Augusto/Documents/TEX FILES/venn3.eps}
\end{figure}`
```

[image: remove /files/venn3.eps]

I want to remove that "FILES/venn.eps" path that accompannies a EPS file at TeX that uses \includegraphics, is there an easy fix?

Comment: This is a different question. Because a new user will not know that the space is what is causing the trouble.

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by the space in the file path:

```
C:/Users/Augusto/Documents/TEX FILES/venn3.eps
```

Solutions:

a) Rename the directory `TEX FILES` to a name without space, e.g. `TeXFiles`.

b) If package `grffile` is loaded, it adds support for spaces in file paths for graphics files for many TeX compilers, but not all drivers.

c) With some TeX compilers quotes can be used to quote the space:

```
"C:/Users/Augusto/Documents/TEX FILES/venn3.eps"
```

See also: [How to include graphics with spaces in their path?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8422/how-to-include-graphics-with-spaces-in-their-path)

Comment: Thanks! It fixed. Also I would add that if your file has an underline character (_), it will also not compile. E.g. I had a file called football_logo.eps, and it took me some time to find out that the problem was simply the path name :/

Comment: @AugustoCamargo Usually, the underscore is not a problem in image file names (unless the file name is printed as simple text somewhere).