# graphicx: including files with multiple . in filename

Tags: graphics

I load the package with:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
```

I use it as follows:

```
\includegraphics{inc/2 aanbod/inc/doc/Vormingplus/inc/img/2 jpg/p. 04-05.jpg}
```

This is the error I get:

---

```
LaTeX Warning: File `inc/2 aanbod/inc/doc/Vormingplus/inc/img/2 jpg/p. 04-05.jp
g' not found on input line 444.


! LaTeX Error: Unknown graphics extension: . 04-05.jpg.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.444 ...c/Vormingplus/inc/img/2 jpg/p. 04-05.jpg}

?
```

---

I think the solution for this problem is clear. graphicx should start seeking at the END of the specified filename, seek to the left for the FIRST APPERANCE OF A DOT.

Could this please be solved?

Comment: This is long-standing documented behaviour, although it is likely that we  (the LaTeX team) will revisit this area soon.

Comment: That is not a bug, it is documented behaviour.

Comment: Also see: [How to include graphics with spaces in their path?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8422/5764)

Comment: It was a design decision: so that `.eps.z` would be detected and handled (a major consideration at the time) also currently you can omit the extension in `\includegraphics` and the file extension will be defaulted, but if you allow `abc.x.jpg`  then use `\includegraphics{abc.x}` you can no longer tell immediately that the extension has been omitted and you have to always try all the extensions even on files that apparently have an extension. certainly in 1994 that would have taken more macro space than we had space for and more time than users would want to wait.

Answer (score 3):

use

```
\usepackage{grffile}
[...}
\includegraphics{"inc/2 aanbod/inc/doc/Vormingplus/inc/img/2 jpg/p. 04-05.jpg"}
```

TeX doesn't like spaces in the file name

Comment: spaces are NOT the problem.

Comment: also not like two dots in path/image name. this confuse it for image extension.