# Trying to render an image under a problem

Tags: graphics

I'm trying to add an image to a problem but it is not rendering the way I want it to. Below is the TeX code and below that a screenshot of what is happening.

```
\documentclass[]{book}

%These tell TeX which packages to use.
\usepackage{array,epsfig}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsxtra}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{graphicx}

%Here I define some theorem styles and shortcut commands for symbols I use often
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defn}{Definition}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{cor}{Corollary}
\newtheorem*{rmk}{Remark}
\newtheorem{lem}{Lemma}
\newtheorem*{joke}{Joke}
\newtheorem{ex}{Example}
\newtheorem*{soln}{Solution}
\newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}

\newcommand{\lra}{\longrightarrow}
\newcommand{\ra}{\rightarrow}
\newcommand{\surj}{\twoheadrightarrow}
\newcommand{\graph}{\mathrm{graph}}
\newcommand{\bb}[1]{\mathbb{#1}}
\newcommand{\Z}{\bb{Z}}
\newcommand{\Q}{\bb{Q}}
\newcommand{\R}{\bb{R}}
\newcommand{\C}{\bb{C}}
\newcommand{\N}{\bb{N}}
\newcommand{\M}{\mathbf{M}}
\newcommand{\m}{\mathbf{m}}
\newcommand{\MM}{\mathscr{M}}
\newcommand{\HH}{\mathscr{H}}
\newcommand{\Om}{\Omega}
\newcommand{\Ho}{\in\HH(\Om)}
\newcommand{\bd}{\partial}
\newcommand{\del}{\partial}
\newcommand{\bardel}{\overline\partial}
\newcommand{\textdf}[1]{\textbf{\textsf{#1}}\index{#1}}
\newcommand{\img}{\mathrm{img}}
\newcommand{\ip}[2]{\left\langle{#1},{#2}\right\rangle}
\newcommand{\inter}[1]{\mathrm{int}{#1}}
\newcommand{\exter}[1]{\mathrm{ext}{#1}}
\newcommand{\cl}[1]{\mathrm{cl}{#1}}
\newcommand{\ds}{\displaystyle}
\newcommand{\vol}{\mathrm{vol}}
\newcommand{\cnt}{\mathrm{ct}}
\newcommand{\osc}{\mathrm{osc}}
\newcommand{\LL}{\mathbf{L}}
\newcommand{\UU}{\mathbf{U}}
\newcommand{\support}{\mathrm{support}}
\newcommand{\AND}{\;\wedge\;}
\newcommand{\OR}{\;\vee\;}
\newcommand{\Oset}{\varnothing}
\newcommand{\st}{\ni}
\newcommand{\wh}{\widehat}

%Pagination stuff.
\setlength{\topmargin}{-.3 in}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0in}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0in}
\setlength{\textheight}{9.in}
\setlength{\textwidth}{6.5in}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

Show the following regions in the complex plane and determine if the the regions are (i) open, (ii) closed, (iii) neither open nor closed.

\begin{enumerate}

    \item $2<|z|$

    \begin{soln}
    \begin{figure}[hbt!]
       \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth]{abs(z) bigger than 2.PNG}
        \end{figure}
    \end{soln}

    \item $Re(z)\ge 2$

    \begin{soln}
    \begin{figure}[hbt!]
       \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth]{Re(z) bigger than 2.PNG}
        \end{figure}
    \end{soln}

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Here is the image of the compiled PDF.

[image]

Why is the image that is coded under the problem and the solution showing up at the bottom of the page for both images? How do I fix this?

Comment: What is `soln`?  How is it defined?  WHat package does it come from?  Best to provide a complete example.

Comment: I added everything i could with the exception of the previous problems I've written up.  I'm very much a novice, I've never been formally taught how to format in tex, and have basically self taugh myself.

Comment: @Eleven-Eleven: Hmmm... spaces in filenames. See [How to include graphics with spaces in their path?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8422/5764)

Comment: Quick answer, get rid of `figure` environment, which naturally floats to a convenient location.  You don't want it to float.  If you need the figure centered, you could replace `{figure}[hbt!]` with `{center}`.

Comment: I know I got the code off of Overleaf's help site...  Let me try it...

Comment: @Werner, so I shouldn't have spaces in my file names?  Should I just reupload the images with no spaces (underscores)?

Comment: @Eleven-Eleven: That's a good alternative; remove spaces and/or use underscores. Try that.

Comment: I just removed spaces and took your advice all, and it worked perfectly.  Thank you!