# Remove the name of picture

Tags: compilation-error

Why the name of picture can not to be removed?

This is my code:

```
>     \begin{figure}
>       \centering
>       \includegraphics[scale=0.7]{One Step Multi Step.png}\\
>       \caption{hehehe}
>     \end{figure}
```

and this is the result:
[image]

What is the problem? So, I can remove the "one step multi step.png".

Comment: You have spaces in your filename. See [How to include graphics with spaces in their path?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8422/5764)

Comment: Please rename your file, without space.

Comment: I _do_ think that you should draw it in LaTeX instead of including it from your computer. There are many tools for you: Ti*k*Z, PSTricks, Asymptote, and even the `picture` environment.

Comment: @JouleV - Really?  As an old TeX user (no graphics whatsoever) I have great admiration for LaTeX graphics packages, but they are still dancing bears.

Comment: @JohnKormylo What does "dancing bears" mean?

Comment: @JouleV Why re-do things you've already done?

Comment: @CarLaTeX What do you mean?

Comment: @JouleV If you already have the image, it's useless to waste time redoing it in TikZ or similar.

Comment: @CarLaTeX Of course, but the output will be better.

Comment: @JouleV Not if you have a deadline

Comment: @CarLaTeX That is another story :))

Comment: @CarLaTeX - The amazing thing about a dancing bear is not how well it dances, but that it dances at all.

Comment: @JohnKormylo lol!