# Text shown at tcolorbox with image

Tags: graphics, xetex, tcolorbox

I'm trying to put an image with spaces at the file name.
There is a way to fix it?

I try with this - [enter link description here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8422/how-to-include-graphics-with-spaces-in-their-path#_=_) -  but it's doesn't help :(

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}


\usepackage{tcolorbox,tikz}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
%\usepackage{etoolbox}
%\patchcmd{\Ginclude@eps}{"#1"}{#1}{}{}

\begin{document}
\tcbox[enhanced,left=0mm,right=0mm,top=0mm,bottom=0mm,boxrule=0.1pt,arc=0mm,drop large lifted shadow]{\includegraphics{this is a rabbit (a).jpg}}
\end{document}
```

And this is the result:
[image]

Here is the picture:
[image]

Thank you!

**P.S. It should be compile with XeTeX**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the `grffile` package:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}


\usepackage{tcolorbox,tikz}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\usepackage{grffile}
%\usepackage{etoolbox}
%\patchcmd{\Ginclude@eps}{"#1"}{#1}{}{}

\begin{document}
\tcbox[enhanced,left=0mm,right=0mm,top=0mm,bottom=0mm,boxrule=0.1pt,arc=0mm,drop large lifted shadow]{\includegraphics{this is a rabbit (a).jpg}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

with xelatex:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}


\usepackage{tcolorbox,tikz}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
%\usepackage{grffile}
%\usepackage{etoolbox}
%\patchcmd{\Ginclude@eps}{"#1"}{#1}{}{}

\begin{document}
\tcbox[enhanced,left=0mm,right=0mm,top=0mm,bottom=0mm,boxrule=0.1pt,arc=0mm,drop large lifted shadow]{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{"this is a rabbit (a)".jpg}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Not working :-(

Comment: @heblyx What do you mean with "not working"?

Comment: I compile your code and see the same result like at my answer...

Comment: You compile it with pdflatex. I need with XeTeX....

Comment: @heblyx I added a second solution for xelatex

Comment: Still not working :-(

Comment: @heblyx Please show your .log file.

Comment: LaTeX Warning: File `''this is a rabbit (a)''.jpg' not found on input line 11.

Comment: Unable to load picture or PDF file '"''this is a rabbit (a)''.jpg"'.
<to be read again>

Comment: @heblyx Please show the compete log file. I'd like to compare it with mine, because I don't have any problems, so maybe different package versions could be the cause.

Comment: Do you know where I can find it?

Comment: @heblyx It should be in the same directory as your .tex file.

Comment: It's crop, but this is what I found... https://anotepad.com/notes/ppm5i3 Thank you!!

Comment: @heblyx This is the pdflatex log file, which does not have a problem? I'd like to see the xelatex one which shows the problem you have

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92341/discussion-between-heblyx-and-user185617).

Comment: Do you know how can I control it? For example at LyX or at TeXWorks? I have no idea how can I change it... Thank you!

Comment: How can show it for you? this is the log file I have...