# I am getting a part of my figure name on the top of the figure. How to overcome it?

Tags: floats

[image]

this figure delivers the flowchart of fragility curve development through IDA

Comment: remove spaces and special letters in the file name

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! You should show us a minimal working example (a small complete document, which we can test) , which produce your problem!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a `just-do-it-for-me` question.

Comment: @Raaja I also don't think this is a do-it-for-me question, the OP does not ask how to draw the figure, but how to remove the filename on top. He does not expect a full script, just some pointers on how to solve the issue. Still it is unclear without an MWE, but that is a different problem.

Comment: @user191173 you could take a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8422/how-to-include-graphics-with-spaces-in-their-path to see if that solves your problem.

Comment: @Marijn I still have to think about it once more. Nevertheless, question was posed by user191292 ;)

Answer (score 0):

two possibilities to avoid this problem:

- remove spaces and special letters in the file name
- use the `grffile` package

Comment: could you provide an example on how this solution could be used to solve the aforementioned problem?