# Figure title created from picture's name - why?

Tags: floats, diagrams

Can anyone tell me why I'm getting that extra title (picture's name .jpg at the top)? I don't want to include it.
[image]

Comment: As far as I could guess from your screenshot, you should remove the blanks in the file name. [How to include graphics with spaces in their path?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8422/134144) should also be worth having a look at.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  For future reference, please don't post screen shots of code.  If you copy and paste the code, then we can copy, paste, and compile your code to see what's happening.

Comment: Thanks leandriis, that works! No blanks. Thanks!

Comment: @leandriis actually with the latest (yesterday) latex release the spaces should work but not having spaces in filenames is always a good idea.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Great. I wasn't aware of this change until now.