# beginner's problem with undefined control sequence \includegraphics

Tags: graphics, includegraphics, undefined

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{C:/Users/Raul/Desktop/Universidad/SEGUNDO/MECÁNICA CLÁSICA I/Práctica 1/informe/images}}

\begin{document}

\includegraphics{sd}

\end{document}
```

I'm new in LaTeX but I think the code is correct. However I have the problem mentioned in the title. Regards

Comment: `MECÁNICA CLÁSICA I` needs to be enclosed in double quotes--similarly `Práctica 1` also should be "Práctica 1"  not just Práctica 1

Comment: You might want to avoid spaces in path names / file names. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8422/134144 might also be worth having a look at.

Comment: it is best to avoid having the full path in graphicspath, it just makes your document not portable (and slows down processing)  can you not just use `\includegraphics{sd}`  ? where is the image file relative to your main document?

Comment: if you do get an error, show the full error message from the log file.

Answer (score 1):

The last `/` in the path is missing.
So it should be:

```
\graphicspath{{C:/Users/Raul/Desktop/Universidad/SEGUNDO/MECÁNICA CLÁSICA I/Práctica 1/informe/images/}}
```

Comment: I changed the directory and I've write the last `/` in the path. However, the problem continues.Now the graphics path is ```\graphicspath{{C:/Users/Raul/Desktop/}}```. What's wrong now?