# Relative path and spaces in path not working on colleagues installation, potentially subfiles related

Tags: paths, subfiles

I have a LaTeX project that will compile on my computer (using MiKTeX), however, on my colleagues computer (using TeX Live), the exact same package will not compile due to path errors. I do use the subfiles package, and they appear to be the same version. I noticed that relative paths do not work, and paths with the space character in them do not work as well. Just curious if anyone has experienced this issue before?

Comment: [How to include graphics with spaces in their path?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8422/how-to-include-graphics-with-spaces-in-their-path)