# How do I get rid of text that labels my images

Tags: graphics, overleaf, text

I am trying to insert images into my document. The compiler I'm using is overleaf. My code is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{images/graph 1.png}
\end{document}
```

which gives this

[image]

How do I get rid of the 1.png

Comment: Rename with graph1.png without space (I hope to have understood your question).

Comment: Surround the image name with quotes: `"graph 1.png"`. See [How to include graphics with spaces in their path?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8422/5764)

Comment: as @Werner says you can use quotes (`"graph 1"`, keep the `.png` out of the quotes) but check your overleaf project is using texlive 2020, you should ot need the quotes in current latex.