# Creative Commons logo

Tags: graphics

I have found the `ccicons` package to typeset Creative Commons logos, but I'm wondering if there is a package that typesets logos like this one:

[image: CC-BY-NC-ND]

If not, how would you do that in TiKz or graphicx?

**Edit:**

I got the svg version of the logo, converted it to PDF with Inkscape, and I'm using the following line:

```
\includegraphics[width=4em]{by-nc-nd.eu.pdf}
```

When I build with `xelatex`, I get:

```
! Unable to load picture or PDF file 'by-nc-nd.eu.pdf'.
<to be read again> 
                   }
l.12 ...ncludegraphics[width=4em]{by-nc-nd.eu.pdf}
```

Comment: Why not just include the graphic with `\includegraphics`?

Comment: I think @TH.'s suggestion is great. In the Creative Commons [download section](https://creativecommons.org/about/downloads)  all logos are available in `eps` or `svg`. IMHO it's worth a shot. __EDIT:__ Andrey was faster than me. =)

Comment: There is value in finding a way to do this so that there is no dependency on any image files at all. The `ccicons` package and some `tikz` should work. However, it's not clear if doing something like that would violate the license for using CC icons in the first place, which seems to say that you _have to_ use image files downloaded from their site.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As TH. mentions, there is really no need to create the logo yourself if there are ready versions (in vector format, too!). Get them [here](https://creativecommons.org/about/downloads).

You might need to convert the logos to the PDF format.

Comment: Wouldn't EPS do instead of SVG->PDF?

Comment: @Raphink: You still have to convert it for pdfTeX, etc. (usually it's done automatically).

Comment: @Andrey: I'm using XeTeX, not pdfTeX, does that make a difference?

Comment: I'm trying with `\includegraphics{by-nc-nd.eu}`. It doesn't work with either pdf or eps. I'm getting : `LaTeX Warning: File `by-nc-nd.eu' not found on input line 12.`

Comment: @Raphink LaTeX gets confused when there is more than one dot in the file name. Rename your {by-nc-nd.eu.eps} to something else and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 7):

I wrote a package which can do this. It has the logos bundled.

The package is called [doclicense](https://github.com/ypid/latex-packages/tree/master/doclicense). Check out the following mini example:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[
    type={CC},
    modifier={by-nc-sa},
    version={3.0},
]{doclicense}
\begin{document}
\doclicenseThis
\end{document}
```

[image]

See: [Inserting a Creative Commons Licence into a LaTeX document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/226788/32320)

Comment: It is beautiful! Great job!

Answer (score 4):

I don't use XeLaTeX, but the error might be because of the `.eu` in `by-nc-nd.eu.pdf`. Enclose everything before the file extension in `{}`:

```
\includegraphics[width=4em]{{by-nc-nd.eu}.pdf}
```

Another neat option for converting eps to pdf is the `epstopdf` package that runs the script of the same name automatically and produces a pdf file that is used for the document:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}

\begin{document}
\includegraphics[width=4em]{{by-nc-nd.eu}.eps}
\end{document}
```

---

Edit:

Related question: [\includegraphics: Dots in filename](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10574/includegraphics-dots-in-filename).

(Less directly related questions about problematic file names and paths: [How to include graphics with spaces in their path?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8422/how-to-include-graphics-with-spaces-in-their-path), [Include image with spaces in path directory to be processed with dvips](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4315/include-image-with-spaces-in-path-directory-to-be-processed-with-dvips), [Specifying an absolute Windows path for \includegraphics](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15387/specifying-an-absolute-windows-path-for-includegraphics))

Comment: Thanks @doncherry. @Martin's comment in the other answer actually gave me the hint as to removing the dot in the name, and I used Inkscape to convert from svg to pdf.

Comment: @Raphink: Yup, I discovered the most recent comments on the other answer the second I after I had posted my answer. I'll leave it up for the sake of `epstopdf` and the option of not changing the file name but using `{}`. For that matter, I'm just searching for some related questions on file names that I saw the other day.

Answer (score 0):

With `pdflatex --shell-escape file.tex` you can include the directly the EPS images availables in Creative Commons with `\includegraphics{file.eps}`, thus saving time avoiding the manual conversion from SVG to PDF. Another advantage, if you want a `file.dvi`, is that you can render the same file.tex with `latex` and `pdflatex` without making any modification.

With `--shell-escape` automatically `pdflatex` make this a copy of the EPS image as `file-eps-converted-to.pdf` that is used for render correctly the document (In spite that the source LaTeX code is still `\includegraphics{file.eps}` and not  `\includegraphics{file-eps-converted-to.pdf}`).

In the case `by-nc-nd.eu.eps` the extra dot is also problematic in this case, but as already stated by Martin Tapankov and doncherry, you can solve easily this renaming the eps file or enclosing the name in `{}`.