# MikTex error for PNG images when trying to produce DVI

Tags: graphics, errors, miktex, png, dvi

I have a `tex` file with `\includegraphic` elements for some PNG images.
I use MikTeX on Windows and the PDF is fine.

Now, I need a DVI so I tried using: `\pdfoutput=0`
This creates a DVI, but only after I remove all the PNG images…
Otherwise I get errors like:

```
! LaTeX Error: Cannot determine size of graphic in math-box-plot.png (no BoundingBox).
```

Comment: You should also consider [compiling to PDF rather than DVI](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2811/is-there-any-reason-to-compile-to-dvi-rather-than-pdf-these-days).

Comment: I converted the PNG files to EPS and used those in includegraphics and it works.

Answer (score 7):

TeX is text based, it cannot determine the size of PNG image itself by default.

A quick solution:

```
\usepackage{bmpsize}
```

And use

```
\usepackage[dvipdfmx]{graphicx}
```

---

It is better to use `extractbb` (also named `ebb`, `xbb`) program to produce `.bb` or `.xbb` file for LaTeX. Use this command in '**Command Prompt**':

`for %i in (*.png) do xbb %i`

(or `for %i in (*.png) do extractbb -x %i`, I'm not sure about MiKTeX.)

And use

```
\usepackage[dvipdfmx]{graphicx}
```

(I use TeX Live, only dvipdfmx supports png images. But MiKTeX seems different, I can't remember well.)

Comment: Leo, you better use `<code> ... </code>` blocks for the command line and similar text to avoid the TeX syntax highlighter.

Comment: @Martin: I did not realise that the two were handled differently

Comment: @Joseph: The syntax highlighting is done in `<pre class="prettyprint lang-tex">` tags around `<code>`. Therefore single `<code>` tags on their own are not highlighted.

Answer (score 3):

Install the program [ImageMagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php), then you can do it on the fly:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\DeclareGraphicsRule{.png}{eps}{.bb}{`convert #1 eps:-}
\DeclareGraphicsRule{.gif}{eps}{.bb}{`convert #1 eps:-}
\usepackage{grfext}
\AppendGraphicsExtensions*{.png,.gif}
\usepackage{bmpsize}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\IncludeGraphics}[2][]{%
  \begingroup
    \let\@found\@empty
    \@for\@type:=\bmpsize@types\do{%
      \ifx\@found\@empty
        \@nameuse{bmpsize@read@\@type}{#2.\@type}%
        \ifbmpsize@ok
          \let\@found=\@type
        \fi
      \fi
    }%
    \ifx\@found\@empty
      \includegraphics[{#1}]{#2}%
    \else
      \includegraphics[{natwidth=\bmpsize@width,natheight=\bmpsize@height,#1}]{#2}%
    \fi
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \IncludeGraphics{lion}\qquad % a png image
  \IncludeGraphics{knuth-tex}  % a gif image
\end{document}
```

btw: you do not need the `\pdfoutput=0` simply run `latex`  instead of `pdflatex`

Comment: It may be too tricky for new TeXers, with no actual advantage. BTW, ImageMagick may be overkill, `bmeps` is enough.

Comment: no, it isn't, and ImagaMagick can be used for any other conversion, hence it is no overkill.

Answer (score 2):

I always make portable latex source equally suitable for compiling both with latex and pdflatex. My remedy is rather simple.

Put `\usepackage{graphicx}` into preample (without any driver specified).

Import `eps` or `pdf` graphics with `\includegraphics{filename}`; latex compiler then loads `filename.eps` whereas pdflatex takes `filename.pdf`. MikTeX automatically converts `eps` into `pdf` on fly if the `epstopdf` package is loaded.

Import `png` graphics with `\includegraphics[nathwith=<XX>bp, natheight=<YY>bp, width=<width>]{filename.png}` with `.png` extension explicitly shown; in that case you dont need to invent `\DeclareGraphicsRule`.  Natural height  and width  of bitmap graphics can be determined from file properties in Windows Explorer or any graphics editor, e.g. Windows Paint.

Comment: Does this work with plain DVI-producing latex, not just pdflatex?

Comment: @Igor Kotelnikov: I can't do "two-character swaped edits"; maybe fix `nathwith`

Comment: @U.Windl if possible neither natwidth nor natheight are recommended You should try to use the natural PNG dpi default of 96dpi in both directions then simply control image import placement with width OR if necessary height