# Cannot determine size of graphic

Tags: graphics, errors, png

I'm trying to include graphics in my Latex-file, which I compiled with latex+dvipdf on OS X. Latex however returns this error: "Cannot determine size of graphic"

My graphic is exported from PowerPoint, so I have tried both .pdf and .png. I get the same errors for both.

Sample code that doesn't work:

```
\begin{figure}[htb]
\begin{center}
\leavevmode
\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{graph.png}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
```

If I have to manually set some measurements of the image, please tell me how I can find out those measurements. I need the image to take up about 80% of text width and be centered. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11193/miktex-error-for-png-images-when-trying-to-produce-dvi (untagged)

Comment: For those who find this via search (like me): another possible reason for the error is that filename contains multiple dots (apparently this confuses texi2pdf and it doesn't recognize the file is png).

Answer (score 195, accepted):

The DVI producing `latex` doesn't support reading the size of PNG, JPG or PDF images. You need to use `pdflatex` for this. Actually `latex` is `pdflatex` in DVI mode in modern distributions, but it can read the sizes only in PDF mode for some reason. You are however able to state the natural size of the images using `natwidth` and `natheight` which will make `latex` compile without error. The produced DVI file will only link to the PDF and the DVI-to-PDF converter will need to include it in the final PDF. AFAIK `dvpdf` doesn't support this but `dvipdfm` does.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth,natwidth=610,natheight=642]{tiger.pdf}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Compile with either

```
pdflatex <file base>
```

or

```
latex <file base>
dvipdfm <file base>
```

Comment: For dvipdfm(x), one should use `dvipdfm` or `dvipdfmx` option of `graphicx` pacakge, and use `extractbb` (`ebb`, `xbb`) program to produce `.bb` or `.xbb` file. `bmpsize` package can also used to replace `extractbb`.

Comment: Thank you for the solution provided. I simply added `\usepackage[dvipdfm]{graphicx} \usepackage{bmpsize}` to my file, and it worked perfectly ! No need to spend time to manually set the bounding box with the time-consuming trial-and-errors method (what I did until this day).

Comment: I used this solution for a png-figure with `latex`, `dvipdfmx` and `graphicx`-package, which worked for me without doing anything additional (2013 TeX Live)

Comment: user41288 solution is great, but there is a typo in the provided code (dvipdfm*x*). The following one worked for me: `\usepackage[dvipdfmx]{graphicx} \usepackage{bmpsize}`

Comment: Just to add: specificying `natwidth` and `natheight` also solved a problem I had with jpgs having *incorrect* bounding boxes (so the tex file compiles, but the image ends up misplaced).

Comment: Thats a lot and a lot. You have done a lot of help

Comment: What are `natwidth` and `natheight` ?

Comment: @SV Natural width and natural height, I presume.

Comment: but how to get these `natwidth` and `natheight` from pdf file?

Answer (score 41):

**A non-Latex solution**

A very fast solution is to convert the `png` file into `eps` format. It can be done easily using graphic software, for instance `Inkscape`.

So, you only need to open the file in `Inkscape` and then `SaveAs` and select `eps` format.

Now change the extension in the `tex` file from

```
\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{tiger.png}
```

to

```
\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{tiger.eps}
```

Comment: excellent and simple solution. I'd add using command-line `convert tiger.jpg eps2:tiger.eps` for another easy & easily scriptable way of converting images, as proposed in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14220700/3551299

Comment: Nice!  I used gimp to convert from .png to .eps https://www.gimp.org/

Comment: Perfect! I used gimp!

Comment: png also doesnt work

Comment: Unfortunately EPS files are about ten times the size of PNG files.

Answer (score 39):

## Fix the file name

I got this error with a pdf file which contained dots in the filename. Removing the dots (except the .pdf, of course) fixed the issue.

## Fix file type detection

The LaTeX graphics/graphicx package uses the first dot to find the extension. Simply adding \usepackage{graphicx} \usepackage{grffile} fixed the issue without changing file names. Package `grffile` changes the algorithm to check for known extensions (option `multidot`, enabled by default).

Comment: yep, here, too.  Is there an open bug report about it anywhere?

Comment: how true it is! very unlikely widely used programs like gimp or inkscape randomly produce wrong images what (Xe)LaTeX can not process. indeed the dot was the reason.

Comment: This is still an issue today (2019-02-20) with the latest updated MikTeX on Windows. My document had been building fine with an outdated MikTeX install, but I started getting this error after updating and came across this answer while trying to resolve the problem. Turns out renaming the image files to not have dots in the names fixed it.

Comment: Confirming this is still an issue (MacTex 2018); switching from dots to underscores in the filename fixed the issue mentioned in the OP.

Comment: Duh. Why are we still using LaTeX?

Comment: Simply adding `\usepackage{graphicx}` `\usepackage{grffile}` fixed the issue without changing file names. The LaTeX graphics/graphicx package uses the first dot to find the extension. Package `grffile` changes the algorithm to check for known extensions (option multidot, enabled by default).

Comment: Had this when I had spaces in the file name. This post saved me, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Sometimes I get this errors when I compile using `latexmk myfile.tex` and include pdf pictures... It's because I forget to compile to pdf, the correct command must be:

```
latexmk -pdf myfile.tex
```

Comment: This is a good and concise solution. However, there are two mistakes in this response. Firstly, the error can also happen when including other image formats (e.g., PNG) and is not limited to .pdf files. Secondly, the `-pdf` option is not to compile to PDF but to compile using the `pdflatex` engine.

Answer (score 3):

I saw this issue with a `jpeg` file. By changing its extension from `.JPG` to `.jpg` (yes, just capital to lower) the error went away.

```
$ pdflatex --version
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013/Debian) restricted \write18 enabled.
```

Answer (score -1):

remove the extension in the latex code, all will be fine. The file keep its extension (correct: jpg if jpg, png if png...).

```
\begin{figure}[htb]
    \begin{center}
       \leavevmode
       \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{graph}
    \end{center}
\end{figure}
```

With the latex compiler, the allowed file type are ps or eps, and with pdflatex, png, jpg (jpeg also is found as extension) or pdf. The file must have its extension, and its real extension. A png is the result of a particular encoding of an image, a jpg another. Latex does not recompile images, it looks for files with the right name, with the extensions it handles. You just have to give it the base of the name, then it manages.

Comment: Not working. If I remove the extension I get file not found, as expected.

Comment: @LuisA.Florit presumably you need to rename the image file to remove the extension from the filename too. Did you do both this and change the reference to the file in the latex?

Comment: No, it's perfect if the file keep its extension. With the latex compiler, the allowed file type are ps or eps, and with pdflatex, png, jpg (jpeg also is found as extension) or pdf. The file must have its extension.