# Beamer, gastex, and include images

Tags: beamer, graphics, include

My goal is to have an image created with `gastex` and include an image (a `png`,`jpg`,`pdf`,.. image) into the `gastex` one. For example, draw an automaton with a smiley picture in a state.

I've read around about including images using `latex`+`dvipdf`. From what I've seen ([here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17734/cannot-determine-size-of-graphic)) it's not possible to include images using these two tools. My problem is that `gastex` compiles only with these two tools and not with `pdflatex`. So I'm stuck..

This is my code (`red-x.jpg` is a standard jpg image):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{gastex}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{picture}(40,20)(-25,-28) 
\gasset{Nw=6,Nh=6,Nmr=10} %nWidth nHeight
\node(A)(25,0){} 
\node[linewidth=0.4,linecolor=orange](B)(12,-10){}
\end{picture}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{red-x.jpg}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

In order to compile with `latex`+`dvipdf` you need to use: `\includegraphics[bb=0 0 20 20]{red-x.jpg}`. Using `xelatex`, the `gastex` image does not show and only the `red-x` shows.

Suggestion?

Comment: use `xelatex`  instead

Comment: `xelatex` doesn't compile my `gastex` image. I.e., the image appears with no lines/nodes/... I'm using Ubuntu if it helps..

Comment: give a complete and minimal example

Comment: added an example to the question

Comment: I get many errors such as `** WARNING ** Interpreting PS code failed!!! Output might be broken!!!`, when compiling with `xelatex`.

Comment: I get the same warning. When using `latex`+`dvipdf` I get `GPL Ghostscript 8.71: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1` and a stack trace which is not informative.

Comment: @Guy I suspect that `gastex` is not compatible with XeLaTeX, because it uses low level specials that `xdvipdfmx` can't understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [jpeg2ps](http://www.pdflib.com/download/free-software/jpeg2ps/) to convert `red-x.jpg` into an `eps` file (note that this is not a 'true' conversion; it just puts a postscript wrapper around the bitmap image).  Using your example with

```
\includegraphics[width=4cm]{red-x.eps}
```

worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

`gastex` uses it's own interface to PostScript which is far different to what PSTricks does. However, with a simple trick we can get it run. We load `pstricks` to get a clean interface to `auto-pst-pdf` and put the gastex image into a `pspicture` environment.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{gastex}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\psset{unit=1pt}
\fbox{\begin{pspicture}(0,-10)(40,20) 
\pstheader{gastex.pro}
\gasset{Nw=6,Nh=6,Nmr=10} %nWidth nHeight
\node(A)(25,0){} 
\node[linewidth=0.4,linecolor=orange](B)(12,-10){}
\end{pspicture}}

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=2cm]{tiger}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

run the example with `pdflatex -shell-escape <file>` and it will create the following output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It seems from the votes-up that your solution works, but I rather not move to `pdflatex` in this presentation.