# !LaTeX Error: Cannot determine size of graphic in simLinkError.pdf (no Bounding Box)

Tags: graphics, pdf, texworks

I'm trying to put a `.pdf` graphic in my `LaTeX` file.  This is usually no problem for me.  I use `pdfLaTeX` in `TeXworks`.  The only difference this time seems to be that I'm using the style files from the journal Statistical Science (http://www.e-publications.org/ims/support/sts-instructions.html).

I've tried several solutions. [This one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17734/cannot-determine-size-of-graphic) and converting the `pdf` to `.eps` or `.ps` all make the error go away, but then there is just a big blank space where the image is supposed to be.  Any ideas?

**Edit:**  Here is the preamble:

```
\documentclass[dvips,sts]{imsart}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\includegraphics[width =  \textwidth]{simLinkError.pdf}
\caption{Blah}  
\label{fig:sim1}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: "Cannot determine size of graphic #1 (no Bounding Box)" error occour when we compile `latex` on a TeX file with non-eps images such as PDF/JPG/PNG etc. To fix this error: You need to run `pdflatex` on the TeX file. Otherwise you need to convert your image to EPS using `convert` and run `latex` on the TeX file.

Comment: @JagathAR, as I mentioned, I am using pdfLaTeX on my TeX file. Is this different than pdflatex?

Comment: @dustin, no, [demo] is not there ...

Comment: Can you post a small example of your problem which has the preamble?

Comment: @dustin, see the updates to my question.  I'm not sure how to post a minimal working example, as there are several style files involved.

Comment: I don't have the class but I improved your MWE so others who do have it can help.

Comment: Remove the `dvips` option to the class. This is all is needed.

Comment: @egreg:  removing 'dvips' does it!  Post as answer and I can give you credit, and bonus points for explaining why.  I wonder why the 'dvips' option was included in the journal's example tex file, and is it a problem for everyone who tries to use graphics.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Options to `\documentclass` are examined by *all* packages. So you're loading `graphicx` with the `dvips` option, which allows only EPS graphics to be imported and is nonsense when the engine is `pdflatex`. So remove it.

```
\documentclass[sts]{imsart}
```

In general `dvips`, `pdftex` or `xetex` should not be used even with packages that know them, such as

- `graphicx`
- `hyperref`
- `geometry`

that can deduce the needed driver by themselves.

Comment: Thanks again!  I'd vote this up if I had enough reputation to do so.

Comment: @zkurtz Don't worry, you'll get it. And I really don't need more reputation, do I? `;-)`

Comment: Using Texlipse under _Project/Properties/Latex Project Properties_ output format **pdf** and build commands **pdflatex** have to be used instead of the corresponding dvi parameters.

Answer (score 5):

```
gs -o /dev/null -sDEVICE=bbox Input.pdf
```

yields

```
%%BoundingBox: 0 0 702 399
```

```
\includegraphics[bb=0 0 702 399]{Input.pdf}
```

Comment: Please state in which sense this posting is an answer to the original query. E.g., do state how the OP might use the information you've provided to help solve his/her issues.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I'm not sure this is an answer to the question.

Comment: It helped me. I could not change teh documentclass command, so this workaround worked.

Comment: How to get the bb for png files?

Comment: This answer is the general answer. The other answer can't help.