# pdflatex, dvips: cannot determine size of graphic in ... (no Bound ingBox)

Tags: graphics, pdftex, pdf, png, dvips

I know that there are threads related to this, but it is really painful...

I would like to insert images saved from a tool into latex.

The images could be saved in any format of the followings: PNG, JPEG, PDF, GIF, BMP. The choice is totally up to me.

The problem is I tried

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
...
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{image.suffix}
\end{figure}
```

The compilation gives me an error `! LaTeX Error: Cannot determine size of graphic in image.suffix (no Bound ingBox).`

[Someone says](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124340/latex-error-cannot-determine-size-of-graphic-in-simlinkerror-pdf-no-bounding) it is due to `dvips`. I do have `dvips` in my `makefile`, but I don't know how to remove it; [Someone says](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17734/cannot-determine-size-of-graphic) it is `pdflatex` which should be used, but I don't know how to modify `makefile` to do so.

```
EPS=    $(FGS:%=%.eps)
%.eps: %.tex $(MACROS)
    latex $< &&         dvips -t letter -z -P pdf -o ${<:%.tex=%.ps} ${<:%.tex=%.dvi} &&        gs -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=bbox ${<:%.tex=%.ps} 2> ${<:%.tex=%.bb} &&         cat ${<:%.tex=%.ps} | perl -ne       'if (/BoundingBox/) { open BB, "${<:%.tex=%.bb}" or die; print <BB>; close BB; } else { print; }' > $@

all: paper.pdf eps
regen: $(EPS)
    make ALLDEPS=1

eps: $(EPS)
SRC=    fonts.tex       paper.bib       macros-paper.tex        packages.tex
paper.pdf: paper.tex $(SRC) $(EPS)
    latex paper.tex &&      bibtex --min-crossrefs=500 paper &&         latex paper.tex &&      latex paper.tex &&      dvips paper.dvi -o paper.ps &&      ps2pdf paper.ps paper.pdf
```

Could anyone help?

**Update1:**

Following the comment of @nickie , I modified `makefile` including all about `epstopdf`, the compilation still gave me an error:

`! Package pdftex.def Error: File 'fg1-eps-converted-to.pdf' not found.` for the tex `\includegraphics[scale=1]{fg1}`, where `fg1.tex` is supposed to generate a figure by `pspicture`.

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: With `latex` you can only use EPS.

Comment: So how could I modify `makefile`?

Comment: Use `pdflatex`; no `dvips` and `gs` are required.

Comment: The thing is that I have some `tex` which generate `eps` that are inserted to `paper.tex`. I don't know if `pdflatex` could handle this and what/where to remove and add in `makefile`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that if you just substitute (with proper indentation: **tabs**) this part:

```
latex paper.tex && \
bibtex --min-crossrefs=500 paper && \
latex paper.tex && \
latex paper.tex && \
dvips paper.dvi -o paper.ps && \
ps2pdf paper.ps paper.pdf
```

with:

```
pdflatex paper.tex && \
bibtex --min-crossrefs=500 paper && \
pdflatex paper.tex && \
pdflatex paper.tex
```

it will work.  If you're using EPS figures and `pdflatex` complains, you can convert them to PDF:

```
%.pdf: %.eps
        epstopdf $<

fg1.pdf: fg1.eps
```

Comment: And probably add `\usepackage{epstopdf}` to the document.

Comment: Thank you, please see my `Update1`...

Comment: If you use the `epstopdf` package, make sure to add the `--shell-escape` option to `pdflatex`.  My answer does not require the `epstopdf` **package**; you'll just have to specify for which figures to call the `epstopdf` **script** in your Makefile.

Comment: @nickie `--shell-escape` is not needed for `epstopdf` with recent TeX Live distributions (≥2012) and, I believe, also with MiKTeX 2.9.

Comment: @egreg: I've forgotten that recent texlive distributions exist!  My ubuntu 12.04 still has texlive 2009...  Anyway, I think the error message he's getting means that `epstopdf` is not executed so this could be one possible reason.