# How to fit a figure within a two-columns text in Latex

Tags: floats

I'm using elsarticle-harv templates, which is a two columns article. I have a hard time trying to fit figures within the two columns the figure goes above the text margins.

So this is how it looks like:

[image]

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width = 0.50\textwidth, natwidth=430,natheight=495]    {outcrops.jpg}
\caption{The study area within Utah from \cite{zu12}}
\label{fig:otc}
\end{figure}
```

Could you please help me solving this?

Comment: You can get current column width with \columnwidth, probably better to use than \textwidth. And natwidth/natheight are useless on a jpg/pdf, etc. Try without them.

Comment: In case removing natwidth/natheight  does not solve your problem, please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Comment: Related ans most likely worth having a look at: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/170578/134144

Comment: So I end up using pdf instead of jpg, and i tool off the natwidth and natheight. It seems working now! Thank you all for your comments.