# LaTeX/Beamer problems with theme

Tags: beamer

My phd advisor send me a tex version of his slides, I try to update it, but when I run it, the result is totally ruined (for example, all the graphs do not download at the right place, the slides are totally "deconstructed", the first page is totally blank, I also see that bullets are not installing correctly, I do not know where it come from).
My knowledge about latex is quite narrowed.

Would you know where would it come from?

Thank you very much in advance.

Images of the result (on the left) with the original (on the right).
[image: On the right, the original slide, on the left, my slide]

[image: On the right, the original slide, on the left, my slide]

Edit: 
It seems that the problem would come from the use of theme... When I do not use any theme, things appear better.

Comment: Hi and welcome, looking at mere screenshots it is impossible to say something. I bet LaTeX is giving you some sort of information, an error or a warning. If your supervisor is a LaTeX user, wouldn't it be much easier to walk into his office and ask him kindly for assistence?

Comment: Hello Johannes and thank you for your answer, yes of course it would be the best solution, except that we are in the week end right now and I will not have an answer from him by email :-). I wanted to see if, by chance, anyone would have experience something like that before.
I could copy paste the code, but the problem is that both code are absolutely the same ! So maybe I miss something like a package or I do not know.

Comment: This could be a thing of 4 minutes for an experienced user in front of your PC. Maybe not. It will take some effort by you to give us useful information to help you. Are there any erros given by LaTeX? Your IDE may help you here, if not, the log-file contains all errors.

Comment: It might be as easy as updating your LaTeX distribution tough.

Comment: Sorry, I am using texniccenter on windows and I know that my phd advisor is on mac (if it can help).
Where can I find the log-file, please? I try to look on the internet but it was not really explicit.

Comment: I will try updating my distribution, but I install miktex quite recently.

Comment: It is in the same directory as your tex-file. windows explorer likes to hide the file ending, but you can toggle them on. Nicola Talbot has written a very good [introduction to LaTeX](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/novices/index.html) that might take you a day reading. But it will save you a real lot of time searching for erros in the future. Maybe this weekend is the perfect one for reading some LaTeX basics ;-)

Comment: As a mac user, he uses TeX Live which is available on Windows, Mac and Linux. Both distributions should be in sync though.

Comment: Ok, the log file was just the notepad file. Thanks but how can I put it in the thread? It is too big for the thread.

Comment: @Antoine What is the first error in the log file? [you might want to search for `! LaTeX Error:`]

Comment: Hello @samcarter, thanks for helping me, here is the first latex error (HSBC is the first image on the first page of my presentation) ! LaTeX Error: Cannot determine size of graphic in ./Figures/HSBC.jpg (no BoundingBox).

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

Comment: @Antoine have a look if something from http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=LaTeX+Error%3A+Cannot+determine+size+of+graphic helps you

Comment: @samcarter but it is strange since I use the original slides. Thanks anyway !

Comment: @Antoine There could be a number of reasons for this problem. To find the error it would be best, if you create a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). Besides this make sure the path to your image is correct and that you compile with `pdflatex`.

Comment: @Antoine can you check if `\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
 \frame{\includegraphics{./Figures/HSBC}}
\end{document}` works?

Comment: @Samcarter, it is a very good idea, thank you. I tried it but it does not find the graphs HSBC: even when I simply put the file HSBC in the same folder than the .tex file (and it works for none of the other ones). What would be missing?

Comment: Are you compiling with pdflatex?

Comment: I do not really understand. I am using texnicenter and when I compile, the output is a pdf (Latex > Dvi > Pdf). Can you precise your question, please?

Comment: I typed "\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

\usetheme{Warsaw}


\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}
    Anything !
  \includegraphics{HSBC}

    \end{frame}

\end{document}"

The "Anything!" only appear if I delete the "usetheme" option. The includegraphics never work. I think the problem would come from the theme (not a specific one). Would someone know this issue?

Comment: Choose LaTeX->PDF instead.

Comment: It worked percusse ! Thank you very much !!!! What was the problem? Where are you from? I want to buy you a drink if you are in Paris right now :-)

Comment: Since you want to include an jpeg image, compile with pdflatex instead of latex which expects .eps files For a more elaborate explanation, have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/17737/36296