# Problem with pstricks and htlatex/tex4ht

Tags: pstricks, tex4ht

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-all}

\begin{document}
  \begin{pspicture}(0,-3)(12,5)
      \psline[linewidth=2pt]{->}(1.5,0)(0,0)
  \end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

This compiles fine with `latex` (not with `pdflatex`) but when run with `htlatex` it leads to the ghostscript error:

```
System call: dvips -E -q -Ppdf -f q.idv -pp 2 > zzq.ps
System return: 0
System call: gs -sDEVICE=pngalpha -sOutputFile=q0x.png -r110x110 -dEPSCrop -dBackgroundColor=16#ffffff -dTextAlphaBits=2 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=2 -q -dbatch -dNOPAUSE zzq.ps -c quit
Error: /configurationerror in --setpagedevice--
Additional information: [/PageSize [0 0]]
Operand stack:
   --nostringval--   (%%BoundingBox: 72 72 72 72)   --dict:1/2(ro)(G)--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   (%%BoundingBox: 72 72 72 72)   1   72   72   false   --dict:1/1(L)--
Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   1951   1   3   %oparray_pop   1950   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   1934   1   3   %oparray_pop   1820   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   %errorexec_pop   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   %ztokenexec_continue   (scanner state)   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   1913   10   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --dict:1/10(L)--   --nostringval--   15   %dict_continue
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:1190/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:82/200(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
Last OS error: Invalid argument
Current file position is 169
GPL Ghostscript 9.16: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
--- Warning --- System return: 256
Entering q.css
Entering q.tmp
```

This code used to work fine. From other examples I suspect that the problem has something to do with `dvips` having trouble determining the bounding box for the image (compare with [Cannot determine size of graphic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17734/cannot-determine-size-of-graphic) -- although the solution given here, of using separate files for each image, is not a viable solution for me), but I have not been able to work out what the problem is.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've tried some `Pstricks` examples and it seems that this error happens only sometimes.

You can easily modify the image conversion process with [make4ht](https://github.com/michal-h21/make4ht#image-conversion), which is included in TL 2015. By default, `dvips` and `ghostscript` are used for image conversion. It isn't really elegant, `dvipng` gives better results (with anti-aliasing), but it seems that it doesn't support `pstricks`. Other possible solution is to use `dvisvgm`, which seems best to me, as vector images are superior to bitmaps for drawings.

I've created a build file for `make4ht`, with two possible options for image conversion: `dvisvgm` for `svg` and `dvips` + `gs` for `png`. The second option uses exactly the same options as default `tex4ht` ones. It doesn't work for your sample file, but it may work for other images.

The file is named `hello.mk4`:

```lua
if mode == "draft" then
  Make:htlatex{}
else
  Make:htlatex{}
  Make:htlatex{}
  Make:htlatex{}
end

Make:image("svg$",
  "dvisvgm -n -o ${output}  -p ${page} ${source}")

Make:image("png$",function(opt)
  local dvips = "dvips -E -q -Ppdf -f  -pp ${page} ${source} -o zz${input}.ps" % opt
  local gs = "gs -sDEVICE=pngalpha -sOutputFile=${output} -r110x110 -dEPSCrop -dBackgroundColor=16#ffffff -dTextAlphaBits=2 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=2 -q -dbatch -dNOPAUSE zz${input}.ps -c quit" % opt
  print(dvips)
  os.execute(dvips)
  print(gs)
  os.execute(gs)
end)
```

it is a Lua script, first few lines drives number of LaTeX runs (`mode` variable is set with `-m` option for `make4ht`, so `make4ht -m draft filename` will run LaTeX only one time, it is real time saver in comparison with `htlatex`)

More interesting are `Make:image` calls, first parameter is file name pattern, it is Lua regex, so it matches `svg` or `png` at the end of filename. Second parameter may be string template, which will be then executed, or function, where you may run commands directly with `os.execute` function. This is used for `png` conversion. I included this version mainly for educational purposes, I would use `svg`

As `png` pictures are produced by `tex4ht` by default, you also need to configure the output to `svg`. It can be enabled with `\Configure{Picture}{.svg} in the custom config file (`hello.cfg`):

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\ConfigureEnv{psmatrix}{\Picture*{}}{\EndPicture}{}{}
\Configure{Picture}{.svg}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

compile the file with

```
 make4ht -m draft -c hello.cfg -e hello.mk4 filename
```

the result:

[image]

and some more interesting example to illustrate the difference between default `png` and `svg` conversion.

`png` version:

[image]

and the `svg`:

[image]

Yes, the `png` version is really truncated, I don't know whether it was caused by wrong options for `dvips` or for `gs.

Comment: Thanks. I think that using svg solves my problem. I haven't quite gotten my application working yet as the real code is hidden in a python app but I am hopeful!

Comment: Michal, thanks very much for this. it has taken me a while to get back to this and now I fully appreciate and understand your code. Thanks also for `make4ht`, it is making my life much easier! (I'm cleaning up a package that I have for converting latex files into html quizzes and your code is letting me support `pstricks` images in the quizzes.)

Comment: @Andrew thanks for your kind words. We fixed the `svg` support in `tex4ht` in the meantime, so it should work even without `.mk4` file now.

Comment: Really?! Perhaps I am doing something wrong but the exampke above does not work for me if I have `\ConfigureEnv{psmatrix}{\Picture*{}}{\EndPicture}{}{}
\Configure{Picture}{.svg}` in my `cfg` file and run this through tex4ht/make4ht. If this fix in texlive2016?

Comment: @Andrew yes, it works for me in up to date TL 2016. `tex4ht` uses  `dvisvgm` for conversion when `svg` pictures are requested now.

Comment: Thanks Michael.  I should have checked and I see now that there was an update to tex4ht on ctan in November, which I don't have installed. For now I will keep on using your mk4 file as I don't want to assume tat people have the latest updates installed. Thank you again, I would up-vote several more times if I could!

Comment: Michal, has this change reverted? I'm finding that some examples like these only work now if I use an `mk4` file to define `Make:image`.

Comment: ...on the other hand, it seems that I should be using `\Configure` with the `pspicture` environment rather than the `psmatrix` environment. If I do this then my example compiles again.

Comment: @Andrew yes, there was some fix for `pstricks` in December, I think it should work now without a need for configurations.

Comment: Ah, thank you. I didn't think of removing my special pstricks hacks. I still need pst2pdf sometimes but this is better...although I have just found a new tikz issue:(

Comment: @Andrew what kind of TikZ issue? I hoped the TikZ update would fix all issues :(

Comment: It's a variation on similar problems that I have had in the past:( I have just posted the details as https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/471458/a-new-problem-with-tex4ht-and-tikz.