# Another problem with pstricks and htlatex/tex4ht

Tags: pstricks, tex4ht

The latex file

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-all,pst-3dplot}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture*}(-4,-4)(4,4)
   \psplotThreeD[linecolor=blue, plotstyle=curve, drawStyle=yLines,
                yPlotpoints=30, xPlotpoints=30, linewidth=1pt](-4,1)(-4,1){
                  x dup mul y dup mul add 1.01 exp}
   \pstThreeDCoor[linewidth=1pt, xMin=-4,xMax=4,yMin=-4,yMax=4,zMin=-2,zMax=6]
  \end{pspicture*}

\end{document}
```

produces the image

[image]

As Michael.h21 pointed out in [Problem with pstricks and htlatex/tex4ht](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/260673/problem-with-pstricks-and-htlatex-tex4ht), there are issues in converting pstricks images when using TeX4ht, which are mostly solved by telling TeX4ht to use dvisvgm. Unfortunately, this doesn't solve the problem in this case: using

```
make4ht -c config.cfg <file>
```

with the configuration file

```
% We are generating HTML + MathML code
\Preamble{xhtml,mathml}

% Output HTML5 doctype instead of the default for HTML4
\Configure{DOCTYPE}{\HCode{<!doctype html>\Hnewline}}

% Custom page opening
\Configure{HTML}{\HCode{<html lang="en">\Hnewline}}{\HCode{\Hnewline</html>}}

\ConfigureEnv{psmatrix}{\Picture*{}}{\EndPicture}{}{}
\Configure{Picture}{.svg}

\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

results in a web page with the image pushed about three pages south and a lot of blank space above it, which is not at all related to Taylor Swift.

Is there a generic fix for this, probably extending Michael's earlier idea? One answer would be to use tikz, for example, instead of pstricks but if possible I'd prefer to keep using pstricks because I have many images like this.

Comment: It seems that the svg file has wrong height. It might be possible to use some tool to resize it to the correct size.

Comment: you can run `pst2pdf <file>`. This creates two additional documents: one with only the `pspicture` environments (`<file>-pst.tex`) and one where these environments are replaced by `\includegraphics` (`<file>-pdf.tex`. The images are created in the subdirectory  `images`. The only problem is that `t4ht` doesn't  take the macro `\PrependGraphicsExtension` into account. The resaon why you have to insert the extension `.pdf` by hand.  Then run `make4ht <file>-pdf.tex` and eveything will be fine.

Comment: @Herbert Perhaps I am going something wrong but this just produces a blank html file for me when I run `pst2pdf` to create `file.pst.tex` and then I run `make4ht -c file.cfg file-pst`. Assuming that it is just me, do you have any idea how likely this approach is to work if I have a "random" latex file that contains a `pspicture` environment? The project that I am working on, in principle, needs to apply to arbitrary latex input (and, before I found this example I thought that it was doing OK.,,)

Comment: With `make4ht` you should run `file-pdf.tex`, not the `file-pst.tex`.

Comment: Thanks @Herbert. I am still having problems getting this to work. I have checked and I have all of the dependencies for `pst2pdf`. It seems that the intention is to run `file-pdf` through pdflatex since `latex file-pdf` and`htlatex file-pdf` both fail saying that they can't find `file-fig-1`. I can fix this by changing the `\includegraphics` commands to explicitly include `file-fig-1.svg`, for example. The other issue is that the scale of the generated image is too large except for `svg`. I can work around both of these issues in my intended application, but I was wondering if `pst2pdf`...

Comment: ...provides another way around this as I did not find this in the documentation. I'm also surprised that `pst2pdf file` and `pst2pdf file.tex` produce different results! Anyway, if you want to post this as an answer I"ll accept it because, these wrinkles aside, this does solve my problem.

Comment: I think this is an error in `dvisvgm`. If you compile your file using `latex` and run `dvisvgm` on the resulting file, it will still be moved downwards. I think the `viewBox` and `width` and `height` attributes in the `svg` file are sometimes calculated incorectly.