# Compile latex-document with pstricks to HTML

Tags: pstricks, html, latex2html

I have a document that I'm currently compiling with pdflatex that contains pstricks-pictures (using `\usepackage[pdf]{pstricks}` and `\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}`)

To publish the document online I want it to be compiled to HTML and the pstricks-pictures to be converted to SVG.

Is there an automated way to do so?

Comment: sure, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/260690/2891 for example