# A new problem with tex4ht and tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tex4ht, make4ht

When run through `pdflatex` the code snippet below produces:

[image]

but when I run it through `make4ht` the following web page, without the numbers, is generated:

[image]

(The difference in scale is an artifact of my skills in taking screenshots.) Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

     \begin{tikzpicture}
        \foreach \x in {-3,...,3} { \draw(\x,0.25) --(\x,0)node[below]{\x}; }
        \foreach \x in {-2.5,...,2.5} { \draw(\x,0.18) --(\x,0); }
        \draw[thick,<->](-3.5,0)--(3.5,0);
        \filldraw[blue!50!white](1.5,0) circle (1mm);
        \draw[red] (-3.5,-1) rectangle (3.5,1); % make bounding box higher
     \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Only the first line of the `tikzpicture` environment is necessary. The rest is just to show that everything else is OK.

I am using TeXLive 2018 and I have just updated all packages.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try the following configuration file:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\tikzset{every node/.style={/pgf/tex4ht node/escape=true}}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

From the TikZ manual:

> Selects the rendering method for a text node with the tex4ht driver.
>   When this key is set to false, text is translated P R into svg text,
>   which is somewhat limited: simple characters (letters, numerals,
>   punctuation, , , . . . ), subscripts and superscripts (but not sub-
>   subscripts) will display but everything else will be filtered out,
>   ignored or will produce invalid html code (in the worst case). This
>   means that two kind of texts render reasonably well:
>
> 1. First, plain text without math mode, special characters or anything else special.
> 2. Second, very simple mathematical text that contains subscripts or superscripts. Even then, variables are not correctly set in italics
>      and, in general, text simple does not look very nice. If you use text
>      that contains anything special, even something as simple as $\alpha$,
>      this may corrupt the graphic.
>
>    \tikz \node[draw,/pgf/tex4ht node/escape=false]
>
> {Example :
>
> ```
> $(a+b)^2=a^2+2ab+b^2$};
> ```
>
> When you write node[/pgf/tex4ht
>   node/escape=true] {htexti}, pgf escapes back to html to render the
>   htexti. This method produces valid html code in most cases and the
>   support for complicated text nodes is much better since code that
>   renders well outside a {pgfpicture}, should also render well inside a
>   text node. Another advantage is that inside text nodes with fixed
>   width, html will produce line breaks for long lines. On the other
>   hand, you need a browser with good svg support to display the picture.
>
> Also, the text will display differently, depending on your browsers,
>   the fonts you have on your system and your settings. Finally, pgf has
>   to guess the size of the text rendered by the browser to scale it and
>   prevent it from sticking from the node. When it fails, the text will
>   be either cropped or too small.

The result on your file:

[image]

Another possibility is to use [an alternative driver](https://github.com/michal-h21/dvisvgm4ht) for `tex4ht`, which use Dvisvgm for the SVG generation. It has much better support for fonts and other advanced SVG features.

The TeX file needs to be updated to use the driver:

```
\documentclass{article}
\ifdefined\HCode
  \def\pgfsysdriver{pgfsys-dvisvgm4ht.def}
\fi 
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

     \begin{tikzpicture}
        \foreach \x in {-3,...,3} { \draw(\x,0.25) --(\x,0)node[below]{\x}; }
        \foreach \x in {-2.5,...,2.5} { \draw(\x,0.18) --(\x,0); }
        \draw[thick,<->](-3.5,0)--(3.5,0);
        \filldraw[blue!50!white](1.5,0) circle (1mm);
        \draw[red] (-3.5,-1) rectangle (3.5,1); % make bounding box higher
     \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Michal. I had this line in before but took it out as it seemed to cause problems. My MWE now compiles properly with `make4ht` but it still fails with `webquiz` with only the top third of the numbers appearing. So evidently I am introducing a bug:( This sounds like the last sentence from your manual entry above... Thanks for telling me where to look.

Comment: @andrew you can also try the `dvsvgm` driver: https://github.com/michal-h21/dvisvgm4ht - but I haven't tested it with updated TikZ yet.

Comment: @Andrew it seems to work nicely, see the update

Comment: I must be doing something stupid as I am getting the error `! Undefined control sequence.
l.33 \NewConfigure`. As I did previously, I am including the code with the line `\ifdefined\HCode
  \def\pgfsysdriver{pgfsys-dvisvgm4ht.def}
\fi` in my class file before `\RequirePackage{tikz}`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Andrew do you have the same problem when you use it in the TeX file? It may be issue that you use it in class.

Comment: @Andrew yes, it is the problem that it is used in class. Does `\AtBeginDocument{\RequirePackage{tikz}} ` work?

Comment: Thank you Michal, you have done it again! It works wonderfully. Will `pgfsys-dvisvgm4ht.def` appear on ctan anytime soon or should I just keep a copy with my code for now? I think that I ready to put my package onto ctan as soon as I have finished going through the documentation. Once/if it is accepted I'll also put it on github. Oh, btw, am I right in thinking that tex4ht still using dvisvgm  if `svg` appears in `\Preamble`?

Comment: @Andrew maybe you can make a copy if you want to distribute it on CTAN. I can see that original TikZ dvisvgm driver changed, so I should investigate that. The dvisvgm driver explicitly requires svg for the picture output, so it will require `dvisvgm` even if `svg` isn't used in the preamble.

Comment: Hi Michal, I tried the example you are saying here, and am getting the error [ERROR]   htlatex: ? 10  Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/pgf/tex4ht node/escape', to wh

Comment: @IshanLevy I don't know, it still works for me. But I would use the [dvisvgm4ht](https://github.com/michal-h21/dvisvgm4ht) driver, it produces better results and doesn't have side effects as the default driver.

Comment: I got it to work! :)