# error using tikz with tex4ht. \Extra \else

Tags: tikz-pgf, tex4ht

I was compiling an old latex file using tex4ht and now it gives an error.

I tried both `pgfsys-dvisvgm4ht.def` and `pgfsys-tex4ht-updated.def` from https://github.com/michal-h21/dvisvgm4ht

The error is

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/keyval.tex))))
! Extra \else.
l.435 \else
```

The same latex file compiles with no error using `lualatex`.

Here is the file and the command I used to compile it

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\ifdefined\HCode 
%downloaded from https://github.com/michal-h21/dvisvgm4ht
%tried both
%  \def\pgfsysdriver{pgfsys-dvisvgm4ht.def}
  \def\pgfsysdriver{pgfsys-tex4ht-updated.def}
\fi 
\usepackage{tikz}             % TikZ and PGF

% Vector Styles
\tikzstyle{load}   = [ultra thick,-latex]
\tikzstyle{stress} = [-latex]
\tikzstyle{dim}    = [latex-latex]
\tikzstyle{axis}   = [-latex,black!55]

% Drawing Views
\tikzstyle{isometric}=[x={(0.710cm,-0.410cm)},y={(0cm,0.820cm)},z={(-0.710cm,-0.410cm)}]
\tikzstyle{dimetric} =[x={(0.935cm,-0.118cm)},y={(0cm,0.943cm)},z={(-0.354cm,-0.312cm)}]
\tikzstyle{dimetric2}=[x={(0.935cm,-0.118cm)},z={(0cm,0.943cm)},y={(+0.354cm,+0.312cm)}]
\tikzstyle{trimetric}=[x={(0.926cm,-0.207cm)},y={(0cm,0.837cm)},z={(-0.378cm,-0.507cm)}]

\begin{document}
\ifdefined\HCode 
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/471458/a-new-problem-with-tex4ht-and-tikz
\tikzset{every node/.style={/pgf/tex4ht node/escape=true}}
\fi 
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (origin) at (0,0) {}; % shift relative baseline
    \coordinate (O) at (2,3);
    \draw[fill=gray!10] (O) circle (1);
    \draw[fill=white] (O) circle (0.75) node[below,yshift=-1.125cm] {Signpost Cross Section};
    \draw[dim] (O) ++(-0.75,0) -- ++(1.5,0) node[midway,above] {$d_i$};
    \draw[dim] (O) ++(-1,1.25) -- ++(2,0) node[midway,above] {$d_o$}; 
    \foreach \x in {-1,1} {
      \draw (O) ++(\x,0.25) -- ++(0,1.25);
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[dimetric2]
        \coordinate (O) at (0,0,0);
        \draw[axis] (O) -- ++(6,0,0) node[right] {$x$};
        \draw[axis] (O) -- ++(0,6,0) node[above right] {$y$};
        \draw[axis] (O) -- ++(0,0,6) node[above] {$z$};
        \draw[fill=gray!50] (0,0,-0.5) circle (0.5); 
        \fill[fill=gray!50] (-0.46,-0.2,-0.5) -- (0.46,0.2,-0.5) -- (0.46,0.2,0) -- (-0.46,-0.2,0) -- cycle;
        \draw[fill=gray!20] (O) circle (0.5);
    \draw (0.46,0.2,-0.5) -- ++(0,0,0.5) node[below right,pos=0.0] {Fixed Support};
    \draw (-0.46,-0.2,-0.5) -- ++(0,0,0.5);
    \draw[fill=gray!10] (O) circle (0.2);
    \fill[fill=gray!10] (-0.175,-0.1,0) -- (0.175,0.1,0) -- ++(0,0,4) -- (-0.175,-0.1,4) -- cycle;
    \draw (-0.175,-0.1,0) -- ++(0,0,4);
    \draw (0.175,0.1,0) -- ++(0,0,4) node[right,midway] {Steel Post};
    \draw (4,0,3.95) -- ++(0,0,-1);
    \foreach \z in {0.5,0.75,...,5} {
      \draw[-latex] (-2*\z/5-0.2,0,\z) -- (-0.2,0,\z);
    }
    \draw[load] (0,0,4) -- ++(0,0,-1.25) node[right,xshift=0.1cm] {$F_{z1}$};
    \draw[fill=gray!20] (-0.25,-0.25,5) -- (4,-0.25,5) -- (4,+0.25,5) -- (-0.25,+0.25,5) -- cycle; 
    \draw[fill=gray!50] (+4.00,-0.25,4) -- (4,+0.25,4) -- (4,+0.25,5) -- (+4.00,-0.25,5) -- cycle; 
    \draw[fill=gray!10] (-0.25,-0.25,4) -- (4,-0.25,4) -- (4,-0.25,5) -- (-0.25,-0.25,5) -- cycle; 
    \draw (4.05,0,4) -- ++(1,0,0);
    \draw (4.05,0,5) -- ++(1,0,0);
    \draw[dim] (4.5,0,0) -- ++(0,0,4) node[midway,right] {$h_1$};
    \draw[dim] (4.5,0,4) -- ++(0,0,1) node[midway,right] {$h_2$};
    \draw[dim] (0,0,3.4) -- ++(4,0,0) node[midway,below] {$b_2$};
    \coordinate (P) at (2,-0.25,4.5);
    \draw (P) -- ++(0,0,0.25);
    \draw (P) -- ++(0.25,0,0);
    \draw[dim] (2.125,-0.25,4.5) -- ++(0,0,-0.5) node[midway,right] {$z_1$};
    \draw[dim] (2,-0.25,4.625) -- ++(-2,0,0) node[midway,below] {$x_1$};
    \draw[load] (2,-2.45,4.5) -- ++(0,2.2,0) node[pos=0.0,right,xshift=0.08cm] {$F_{y1}$};
    \draw[axis,dashed,-] (O) -- (0,0,5);
    \draw (0,0,5.5) -- ++(4,0,0) node[midway,above] {$w_{z}$};
    \foreach \x in {0,0.25,...,4} {
      \draw[-latex] (\x,0,5.5) -- ++(0,0,-0.5);
    }
    \draw (-0.2,0,0) -- ++(-2,0,5) node[above,xshift=0.5cm] {$w_{x}=\frac{z}{h_1+h_2} w_0$};
  \end{tikzpicture} %
\end{document}
```

The command is  `make4ht -ulm default -a debug foo.tex "htm"`

Using `lualatex foo.tex` no error and gives

[image]

Obviously I did not write the Latex code in the above, as I am very much a newbie in tikz. The code by Paul Gessler from https://texample.net/tikz/examples/signpost/

I remember compiling this OK in tex4ht before. Why does it fail now?

I am using TL 2021

```
>which make4ht
/usr/local/texlive/2021/bin/x86_64-linux/make4ht
>make4ht --version
make4ht version v0.3k
```

Comment: I think that the main issue is caused by the `standalone` class, it probably got updated and TeX4ht support is broken. Other than that, don't define any dvisvgm driver and remove conditional code for TeX4ht, and your images should compile. They compile without errors with the Article class. So only `standalone` needs to be fixed.

Comment: @michal.h21 You are right. It compiled OK in article class. something must have changed. OK no problem. I also removed the driver call. But when I compile I get message `TeX4ht info: Using dvisvgm4ht TikZ driver. Put \def \pgfsysdriver {driver-name} to your document before use of TikZ if you want to another driver`  So you are saying one no longer needs to use `\def\pgfsysdriver{pgfsys-dvisvgm4ht.def}` anywhere when compiling with tex4ht?  When did this change happen? I need to update my latex files in this case then. Thanks.

Comment: `pgfsys-dvisvgm4ht.def` is used by default for some time. It doesn't hurt if you have it in your document, but you don't need to load it explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is with the `standalone` class, which clashes with TeX4ht quite badly. Try this version of your file:

```
\catcode`\:=11
% we must use the class/before hook, because \:IfFileExists don't exist now, 
% it is initiated before class is loaded by TeX4ht
\AddToHook{class/before}{\let\IfFileExists\:IfFileExists}
\catcode`\:=12
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}             % TikZ and PGF

% Vector Styles
\tikzstyle{load}   = [ultra thick,-latex]
\tikzstyle{stress} = [-latex]
\tikzstyle{dim}    = [latex-latex]
\tikzstyle{axis}   = [-latex,black!55]

% Drawing Views
\tikzstyle{isometric}=[x={(0.710cm,-0.410cm)},y={(0cm,0.820cm)},z={(-0.710cm,-0.410cm)}]
\tikzstyle{dimetric} =[x={(0.935cm,-0.118cm)},y={(0cm,0.943cm)},z={(-0.354cm,-0.312cm)}]
\tikzstyle{dimetric2}=[x={(0.935cm,-0.118cm)},z={(0cm,0.943cm)},y={(+0.354cm,+0.312cm)}]
\tikzstyle{trimetric}=[x={(0.926cm,-0.207cm)},y={(0cm,0.837cm)},z={(-0.378cm,-0.507cm)}]

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (origin) at (0,0) {}; % shift relative baseline
    \coordinate (O) at (2,3);
    \draw[fill=gray!10] (O) circle (1);
    \draw[fill=white] (O) circle (0.75) node[below,yshift=-1.125cm] {Signpost Cross Section};
    \draw[dim] (O) ++(-0.75,0) -- ++(1.5,0) node[midway,above] {$d_i$};
    \draw[dim] (O) ++(-1,1.25) -- ++(2,0) node[midway,above] {$d_o$}; 
    \foreach \x in {-1,1} {
      \draw (O) ++(\x,0.25) -- ++(0,1.25);
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[dimetric2]
        \coordinate (O) at (0,0,0);
        \draw[axis] (O) -- ++(6,0,0) node[right] {$x$};
        \draw[axis] (O) -- ++(0,6,0) node[above right] {$y$};
        \draw[axis] (O) -- ++(0,0,6) node[above] {$z$};
        \draw[fill=gray!50] (0,0,-0.5) circle (0.5); 
        \fill[fill=gray!50] (-0.46,-0.2,-0.5) -- (0.46,0.2,-0.5) -- (0.46,0.2,0) -- (-0.46,-0.2,0) -- cycle;
        \draw[fill=gray!20] (O) circle (0.5);
    \draw (0.46,0.2,-0.5) -- ++(0,0,0.5) node[below right,pos=0.0] {Fixed Support};
    \draw (-0.46,-0.2,-0.5) -- ++(0,0,0.5);
    \draw[fill=gray!10] (O) circle (0.2);
    \fill[fill=gray!10] (-0.175,-0.1,0) -- (0.175,0.1,0) -- ++(0,0,4) -- (-0.175,-0.1,4) -- cycle;
    \draw (-0.175,-0.1,0) -- ++(0,0,4);
    \draw (0.175,0.1,0) -- ++(0,0,4) node[right,midway] {Steel Post};
    \draw (4,0,3.95) -- ++(0,0,-1);
    \foreach \z in {0.5,0.75,...,5} {
      \draw[-latex] (-2*\z/5-0.2,0,\z) -- (-0.2,0,\z);
    }
    \draw[load] (0,0,4) -- ++(0,0,-1.25) node[right,xshift=0.1cm] {$F_{z1}$};
    \draw[fill=gray!20] (-0.25,-0.25,5) -- (4,-0.25,5) -- (4,+0.25,5) -- (-0.25,+0.25,5) -- cycle; 
    \draw[fill=gray!50] (+4.00,-0.25,4) -- (4,+0.25,4) -- (4,+0.25,5) -- (+4.00,-0.25,5) -- cycle; 
    \draw[fill=gray!10] (-0.25,-0.25,4) -- (4,-0.25,4) -- (4,-0.25,5) -- (-0.25,-0.25,5) -- cycle; 
    \draw (4.05,0,4) -- ++(1,0,0);
    \draw (4.05,0,5) -- ++(1,0,0);
    \draw[dim] (4.5,0,0) -- ++(0,0,4) node[midway,right] {$h_1$};
    \draw[dim] (4.5,0,4) -- ++(0,0,1) node[midway,right] {$h_2$};
    \draw[dim] (0,0,3.4) -- ++(4,0,0) node[midway,below] {$b_2$};
    \coordinate (P) at (2,-0.25,4.5);
    \draw (P) -- ++(0,0,0.25);
    \draw (P) -- ++(0.25,0,0);
    \draw[dim] (2.125,-0.25,4.5) -- ++(0,0,-0.5) node[midway,right] {$z_1$};
    \draw[dim] (2,-0.25,4.625) -- ++(-2,0,0) node[midway,below] {$x_1$};
    \draw[load] (2,-2.45,4.5) -- ++(0,2.2,0) node[pos=0.0,right,xshift=0.08cm] {$F_{y1}$};
    \draw[axis,dashed,-] (O) -- (0,0,5);
    \draw (0,0,5.5) -- ++(4,0,0) node[midway,above] {$w_{z}$};
    \foreach \x in {0,0.25,...,4} {
      \draw[-latex] (\x,0,5.5) -- ++(0,0,-0.5);
    }
    \draw (-0.2,0,0) -- ++(-2,0,5) node[above,xshift=0.5cm] {$w_{x}=\frac{z}{h_1+h_2} w_0$};
  \end{tikzpicture} %
\end{document}
```

I've removed all your special code for TeX4ht, as it does more harm than good. And also added this code before `\documentclass`:

```
\catcode`\:=11
% we must use the class/before hook, because \:IfFileExists don't exist now, 
% it is initiated before class is loaded by TeX4ht
\AddToHook{class/before}{\let\IfFileExists\:IfFileExists}
\catcode`\:=12
```

The main problem is that TeX4ht patches `\IfFileExists` command quite early in the processing, and it adds some commands at its end, which causes `standalone` to execute code for both true and false conditions. From this then comes a cascade of errors. I am not sure why TeX4ht patches it, it is part of the original code. I think we can safely remove the patch.

Anyway, this is the result:

[image]