# Inserting images using TeXnicCenter

Tags: graphics

I'm trying to insert images using the `graphicx` package. However, when I compile the code, it comes up with an error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Cannot determine the size of graphic in C:/Users/cst2/Pictures/MathsC.png (no BoundingBox).
```

My file directory is as follows:

```
\graphicspath{ {C:/Users/cst2/Pictures/} }
```

and the call function is as follows:

```
\includegraphics{MathsC.png}
```

can anyone tell me what could be causing this error?

Many thanks.

Comment: I don't think this issue is related to TeXnicCenter, you may consider to remove  this tag from this question.

Comment: Use slashes instead of backslashes in the path `C:/Users/cst2/Pictures`

Comment: I also thought that was the issue, however, when I changed it to slashes, it would not recognise the file directory at all, I suspect it may be because I am using a Windows system

Comment: @UlrikeFischer isn't a `/` require at the end (ie. `C:/Users/cst2/Pictures/`) ?

Comment: @DamienDtx: Yes, but as in the question there is a slash there I hope Xylius didn't forgot it.

Comment: @Xylius: Slashes works fine on windows. I don't know why it doesn't find the pictures but: 1. spaces in files names are bad and 2. absolute pathes are bad.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: I have since tried and changed the format to slashes instead of backslashes yet nothing has changed, however, following your advice, ill leave them as slashes

Comment: path in error message and graphicspath seem to be mismatched. are you sure you're using the right path?

Comment: @Xylius: The error refers to boundingbox, which suggests this answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17734/cannot-determine-size-of-graphic