# LaTeX Error: Option clash for package graphicx

Tags: graphics, errors, png, wide-image

I have been trying to implement the solution that is mentioned [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17734/cannot-determine-size-of-graphic) to solve the error, "Cannot determine size of graphic".

However when I want to add `\usepackage[dvipdfmx]{graphicx} \usepackage{bmpsize}`; I get the error "Option clash for package graphicx."

I am using overleaf and I just can't figure out what is going on because I just copied the following code that I had used there before for another project which was working. Now it gets the error "Cannot determine size of graphic".

```
\begin{figure}[!htbp]
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{05_cost.png}
  \centering
  \caption{Probability density distribution comparisons of the true target and resampled instance spaces}
  \label{fig:kd}
\end{figure}
```

One additional thing is, now I had to give the name as `05_cost.png` while before, it basically worked only with `05_cost` and simply just by using the `graphicx` package.

I would be so happy to hear some advices.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: It looks like the `graphicx` package is loaded twice.  Check carefully your `\usepackage` declarations.  **Edit:** What happens *wihout* the `bmpsize` package?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: the full error message which you have not shown says exactly what the clashing options are.

Comment: With the information you give, I'm not sure what really happens but how about passing `dvipdfmx` option as a global option (like `\documentclass[dvipdfmx, <other options>]{article}`)? It can avoid option clash caused by packages which internally load the `graphicx` package.

Comment: I thought I checked that carefully, now realized there is a package that I use which included graphicx inside. When I removed it, I did not get an error, However now the figure is not actually showed, it is just blank. Would you have any idea ?

Comment: As previously mentioned, you've not provided sufficient information for anybody to diagnose the problem. Did you try @DavidCarlisle 's suggestions?

Comment: Try loading `graphicx`, with the options you want, *before* that other package.  If that doesn’t work, try adding `\PassOptionsToPackage{<your options>}{graphicx}` before the `\usepackage` declaration for that other package.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I did remove the package that was including graphicx  inside as @DavidCarlisle suggested and this error was gone. However the image then did not show up even though there was no error. (I am using overleaf ) At the end, I just created a new project and removed the standard package (from my class) that I was using for the formatting and everything worked. So i am still not sure what was the problem that was causing the blank image. Thanks a lot for everyone for your helps anyways. Now I have functioning code.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the op solved it by his own as mentioned in the last comment.