# Width of figures in subfolders cannot be controlled with \textwidth

Tags: graphics

I am using the standard graphics package and I usually keep my figures in the current working directory. However, now I have to keep them in a separate folder.

Thus I included `\graphicspath{{figures/}}` before `\begin{document}`
and I include the graphics as `\includegraphics[width=0.95\textwidth]{figures/pic.jpg}`.

However, the figure appears in a very large size. If I use `\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{figures/pic.jpg}` it appears to be able to control it but I have more than 200 figures and many of them are sub-figures which I need to control with `\textwidth`. It will be impossible for me to play around with the scale of each figure. I have never had an issue like this when the figures are in the same folder. Does someone know why using `\textwidth` for controlling the width of figures in a subfolder does not work?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this: Look at [Cannot determine size of graphic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17734/cannot-determine-size-of-graphic).

The main issue is that when building LaTeX -> DVI -> PDF, DVI does not read any PNG, JPG and PDF figures. If I use LaTeX -> PDF it works perfectly.

Comment: this is unrelated to using folders, so you might want to edit the question so as not to confuse future readers (assuming you did asked the question, username seems to have changed)