# Error: LaTeX Error: Cannot determine size of graphic in PRV_internal_structure.jpg (no BoundingBox)

Tags: graphics, miktex

I use Miktex and Winshell to edit my script. I want to inset imae. Whenever I compile my code I get this error:

> Error: LaTeX Error: Cannot determine size of graphic in
>   internal_structure.jpg (no BoundingBox).

This is the minimal script:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,twocolumn,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!b]
  \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{internal_structure.jpg}
  \end{center}
  \caption{\small A general overview}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

I found similar previous posts but please do not mark this as duplicate. I still can not solve the problem despite previously posted solutions. For example, this post [Post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17734/cannot-determine-size-of-graphic) suggests the following answer:

> You need to use pdflatex for this. Actually latex is pdflatex in DVI
>   mode in modern distributions, but it can read the sizes only in PDF
>   mode for some reason.

But I do not get how to use pdflatex? I already installed MikTex (basic-miktex-2.9.5872) package which should include the pdflatex and still get the error.

I need to get rid of this error. Can you please help me identify the source of the problem and how to solve it?

Comment: miktex includes several different programs including latex and pdflatex. on the command line it is simply use the command `pdflatex file` instead of `latex file` if your editor is running the command for you, it depends on the editor you are using

Comment: I use Winshell editor. I do not use the command line. I use the GUI so thats why I do not get how to deal with this problem.

Comment: someone will know or presumably that editor has a help menu:-) it will be just the same as whatever you do for latex but just a different key or different menu choice or whatever., either way the question as asked (about the graphics error) is a duplicate , you could instead ask the  different question "how do I run pdflatex from winshell" (i don't know the answer to that one)

Answer (score 2):

Hei, you just need to run it by using "PDFlatex" instead of using "texify"

Here is the process to do so:

In winedit go to the "Tex" option, then "PDF" option and then click on "PDFLatex". You will be able to add `.jpg`/`.png` any picture format in your LaTeX. Remember to use `\usepackage{graphicx}` in the beginning. I am attaching the snapshot for your convenience. Hope your problem will work. :)

[image]

Comment: Use `pdflatex  <filename.tex>` command