# Create .dvi and .ps file with Overleaf

Tags: compiling, overleaf, ps

I need to submit the final version of my paper to a conference but they request a .zip file that including .ps and .dvi file of my .tex document. Since my whole project is on Overleaf, I want to know how can I accomplish it?

Here, what I have done so far:

- First I learned that I have to change compiler from pdflatex to latex... Done!
- Then when I compile, it returned errors that request natural size of figures. And I used the answer given here:
- [Cannot determine size of graphic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17734/cannot-determine-size-of-graphic)

Now it doesn't yell out me, compiles with no error, however still can't see the figures in the output. I don't even know if it is normal or not. Also, can't download a .div file, still gives .pdf file to me.

About .ps file, I haven't there yet, didn't try. But if you know what to do, please inform me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Before trying to convert everything to the latex+dvips route, better ask at the conference if they accept also pdf - insisting on dvi/ps is rather odd nowadays.

Comment: Are all your images already in .eps format? You can download the .dvi file via https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/View_generated_files . And if it's really confirmed that you really do need a .ps file as well I'll post a more complete answer later

Comment: @LianTzeLim my images are actually pdf files: `\includegraphics[width=0.77\textwidth,natwidth=580,natheight=887]{per10.pdf}` Now you tell me convert them to .eps ? :/

Comment: Wellll yes the latex+dvipdf compiler can only handle .eps images.

Comment: @LianTzeLim thanks bro, I converted them to eps and I downloaded the .dvi file. Now I need the .ps file. I search on web but can't see any clear answer. Maybe it is because of my stupidity, I don't know...

Comment: Don't use the natwidth and natheight keys, they make no sense and can even harm.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer well, they did indeed so I removed them, now it works like a charm, except creating a .ps file... Still looking for it.

Comment: well the ps-file is an intermediary file, so you should tell  overleaf to run the latex-dvips-ps2pdf route and then it should be in the output files. @LianTzeLim can probably tell you how to do it.

Comment: Now I found a tool named pdftops.exe and it converts somethings but gives error like `Config Error: No display font for 'Symbol'`. Also, I converted that .ps file to .pdf file with an online tool, it returns a pdf file with only the first page of my paper.

Comment: @stackme try the command `dvips -Ppdf filename.dvi` through `MS-DOS` prompt, and you will get a `.ps` file

Comment: @MadyYuvi where can I download this dvips's executable file? It seems like a package when I search for it.

Comment: @stackme It comes along with `MikTeX` setup, if you go for `LaTeX->dvips->PS2PDF`, then `MikTeX` is recommendable...

Comment: In your Overleaf project add a file named `latexmkrc` (without extension), and add this line in it: `END { system ('dvips -Ppdf output.dvi'); }` then recompile. (`$pdf_mode=2` doesn't work) You can also use https://cloudconvert.com/ to convert dvi -> ps

Comment: @LianTzeLim Thank you so much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*[Disclaimer: I'm a support personnel at Overleaf.]* So to recap/summarise the comments:

1. Set your Overleaf project's compiler to "LaTeX" using the steps [here](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/Choosing_a_LaTeX_Compiler).
2. You'll need to make sure all your images are in `.eps` format, because that's what `latex` can handle. There's no need to use `natwidth` nor `natheight` with `\includegraphics`; in some situations they may even cause errors.
3. Add a `latexmkrc` file to your Overleaf project; place it in the project's top level. Add the following line in it:

```perl
END { system ('dvips -Ppdf output.dvi'); }
```

(Usually `$pdf_mode=2` would make sure that a `.dvi` and a `.ps` is generated, but this doesn't work on Overleaf.)

4. Recompile, and then download the `.dvi` and `.ps` files using the steps [here](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/View_generated_files).

If you prefer not to add a `latexmkrc` file, you can skip step 3 and use step 4 to download just the `.dvi` file. You can then run `dvips -Ppdf yourfile.dvi` on a local computer; or use https://cloudconvert.com to convert it to `.ps`.