# Getting a .dvi output from Overleaf

Tags: eps, overleaf, dvi

[This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/506932/create-dvi-and-ps-file-with-overleaf) deals with what I am trying to achieve above, but when I changed the compiler to LaTeX from PdfLaTeX, my output PDF only had 3 pages, when the entire document is supposed to be 8 pages long. I proceeded to change the very first `.jpeg` into a `.eps` and included the EPS file instead, but I still could not see it in my output PDF. What am I doing wrong here?

Should I look into compiling this file with other compilers?

Comment: Hello there! Tom from Overleaf Support Team here. I don't know what could cause this. But you can reach me on Overleaf support email address and we can see what's going on there. Then if it's something worth sharing with others, I will make an answer here.

Comment: @yo' I have submitted my issue as an email. Looking forward to your response.