Viewing .dvi files
I want to know how to view .dvi files using Overleaf as my TeX editor. I have a dvi file version of lecture note downloaded on my computer.

Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/506932/create-dvi-and-ps-file-with-overleaf. For example you can open .dvi file here: https://fileproinfo.com/free-viewer/dvi

Which operating system do you use?

Why dvi? Hardly anyone uses taht format anymore.

If you use linux or mac, you can use xdvi. For windows, there also is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yet_Another_Previewer

I use windows operating system.

@Sebastiano the free viewer is apparently not working.

@PlayerUnknown1098 Try this: https://filext.com/file-extension/DVI

Thanks @Sebastiano it works now.

Try yap.exe , which should be in your Latex installation. Have a look in or near ,,,\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64

@PlayerUnknown1098 Happy to help you. A suggestion use, when is possible, tools on line. Bye.

Note that I think the correct display will depend on the availability on your system of the appropriate fonts because I think the DVI only contains boxes.
