# Texts are misaligned with respect to the plot when using gnuplot, latex and dvipdfm; what is the solution?

Tags: pdftex, gnuplot, dvipdfmx, epslatex, dvipdf

When I use the following gnuplot code and then compile the generated `tex` file with `latex` and `dvipdf` commands, I simply get what I want.
**`gnuplot` code:**

```
set terminal epslatex standalone
set output "plot.tex"
plot sin(x)
```

**compilation code:**

```sh
latex plot.tex
dvipdf plot.dvi
```

[image]

Now I want to use `dvipdfm` instead of `dvipdf`, since I want to include an image (named `T.pdf`)
in my plot area using `\includegraphics{T.pdf}` (with `dvipdf`, it is not
possible, from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/17737/211422)). To do so, I follow the following listings, but I get the figure below.
**`gnuplot` code:**

```
set terminal epslatex standalone
set output "plot.tex"
set label at screen 0.5,0.5 '\includegraphics[natwidth=.5in,natheight=.5in,scale=.25]{T.pdf}'
plot sin(x)
```

**compilation code:**

```bash
latex plot.tex
dvipdfm plot.dvi
```

**T.pdf :**
[image]

[image]

As you can see, the plot is misaligned with respect to the texts. Passing the
option `dvipdfm` in the preamble, i.e. `\usepackage[dvipdfm]{graphicx}` in `plot.tex` also
doesn't solve the problem.

## Question

My question is simply, how to generate the correct figure when including an image in the plot area as well?

Comment: Did you try to do it with `pstricks`?

Comment: @Bernard I don't know what is it; so, what is it !?

Comment: @Bernard Can you tell me how should I use `pstricks` in my problem?

Comment: You can plot functions with the `pst-plot package`. Take a look at its documentation, which has many examples, and ask a question if you have any difficulty. Note it's simpler to compile with `xelatex --shell-escape`. The fundamental command f or the sine function would simply be `\psplot[algebraic]{-10}{10}{sin(x)}`.

Comment: For your first question, `pstricks` is a package which is a sort of  interface between latex and Adobe postscript.

Comment: @Bernard I used `sin(x)` here only for the purpose of illustration. My actual data is a two-column text file which I plot it using `gnuplot`; but I have the same problem there, i.e., the plot is misaligned with regard to the texts.

Comment: ?? How can you plot a text file? Maybe you mean some .csv file?

Comment: @Bernard It is a raw file (no extension in the file name) with two numerical columns where the delimiter between the columns is space.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119013/discussion-between-bernard-and-alish).