# How/where to find LyX error?

Tags: lyx, compilation-error

I have a very large LyX file. When outputting, I get this error:

[image]

How do I find where this error is? What should I look for in the "Complete Log"?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: See: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17734/47927

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In LyX, go to

Document > Latex log > Open containing directory > (Opens some folder like "C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Temp\lyx_tmpdir.XXX\lyx_tmpXXX") > Open "XXX.txt" or "XXX.log" > Now in the text file, search for "Error"

And you should find something like this:

`! LaTeX Error: Cannot determine size of graphic in ../../../../AppData/Desktop/ XXX/YYY.pdf (no size specified).`

where the YYY.pdf should tell you where the error is. (You can e.g. in LyX go to View > Outline Pane > Graphics > search for "YYY".)