# Graphic size error in lyx

Tags: graphics, table-of-contents, floats, lyx, windows

i am  getting this error :

Latex error :cannot determine size of graphic

Try typing    to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X   to quit.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hello. Have you seen this question? It might be helpful: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17734/cannot-determine-size-of-graphic