# Including graphics for both DVI and PNG

Tags: graphics, pdf, dvi, png

I'm asking a question is quite similar to this one (where I don't seem to be able to leave comments):

[MikTex error for PNG images when trying to produce DVI](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11193/miktex-error-for-png-images-when-trying-to-produce-dvi)

I'm producing a PDF document, but I'm using the DVI previewer inside LeD while doing so. Including graphics is a bit problematic. Suppose I want to include a file simple_ambiguity.png.

```
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{simple_ambiguity.png}
```

doesn't work with the DVI, because of a bounding box error. This is a nuisance because I don't actually care about having the graphics display accurately inside the DVI, or even having it take up the right amount of space -- I just want it to compile.

At the moment I'm using a workaround: I'm creating a dummy `empty picture'  file simple_ambiguity.eps whose dimensions I don't really care about, and then writing

```
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{simple_ambiguity}
```

But this is a nuisance because I have to manually create an eps every time I add a new picture. What I'm looking for is some simple fire-and-forget solution that will make the DVI just compile.

(Of the answers in the question I linked to, the first seems to involve manually creating bounding boxes, and the second involves invoking ImageMagick on every compile, which will be unnecessarily slow & introduce a rather awkward dependency.)

Comment: I'm confused. If you are using the `.dvi` route, you need `.eps` graphics for final output. On the other hand, if you are using `.png` graphics you must be using PDF output mode, so where does the `.dvi` part come in?

Comment: You need some [minimum reputation to leave comments everywhere](http://tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment). But you can always edit and/or comment your own quaestions.

Comment: @Joseph Wright: I am using a IDE called LeD, and its built-in viewer only supports DVIs. As I said, I don't actually care about having the graphics display accurately inside the DVI, or even having it take up the right amount of space -- I just want it to compile so I have a rough preview available while editing.

Comment: @Mohan I still don't understand: you are using the `dvips` route, so you _have_ to have `.eps` graphics for your final PDF production, quite independent of the viewer in LeD.

Comment: @Joseph Wright: LeD allows one to invoke both latex and pdflatex. I use latex (frequently) while editing, together with the built-in previewer, to check everything except the pictures. I then use pdflatex to get the document I actually want to distribute.

Comment: @Joseph Wright: this is the basic approach I was using... http://www.math.northwestern.edu/comp-help/including_graphics.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you just want the image to go away in `dvi/dvips` mode then:

```
\makeatletter
\def\temp{dvips.def}
\ifx\Gin@driver\temp
\def\Ginclude@graphics#1{\def\temp{#1}---image \expandafter\strip@prefix\meaning\temp---}
\fi
\makeatother
```

In your preamble will have that effect.

Comment: Thank you. I think this is almost exactly what I want. Is there an easy way to have it e.g. leave two inches of vertical whitespace instead of including nothing?

Comment: [I can insert \bigskip before the ---image, but \vspace and \vskip don't work.]

Comment: put the text into a parbox and use the optional parbox arguments to specify width and height of the box

Comment: Nice one, does the job for me!

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Is there also an extension to this trick to disable the bibliography when generating a dvi file?

Comment: @BertjanBroeksema It seems a strange request, but anyway the `ifpdf` package allows you to test for pdflatex and do different things depending.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Not that strange if you know the goal (I hope). When I'm writing I'd like to keep track of wordcount. I found catdvi to get plain ascii from latex and now I want to get rid of the reference when generating the dvi so that I can run 'wc -w' on the output of catdvi and get a reasonable estimate.

Comment: @BertjanBroeksema OK:-) although I'd be surely tempted to tell anyone asking for a word count to go away and not be silly, I understand that that's always not a good idea if trying to get things published or theses accepted;-) (you could try `pdftotext` on the pdf rather than have dvi just for that)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle argh =:D. Cleaned up my tex files immediately! Thanks for the tip! Although, pdftotext does include the references, which can be a significant amount of "words" even though they shouldn't be counted as such.

Comment: @BertjanBroeksema you could use sed or perl or whatever to just delete all lines of the text file after "References" or whatever your title is.

Answer (score 8):

you can use png or gif images also with the dvi route, but you have to define some graphic rules for the converting. The following needs

```
latex <file>
dvips -R0 <file>
ps2pdf <file>.ps
```

The program `convert` must be installed. It is part of the ImageMagick bundle

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}    
\DeclareGraphicsRule{.png}{eps}{.bb}{`convert #1 eps:-}
\DeclareGraphicsRule{.gif}{eps}{.bb}{`convert #1 eps:-}
\usepackage{grfext}
\AppendGraphicsExtensions*{.png,.gif}
\usepackage{bmpsize}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\IncludeGraphics}[2][]{{%
    \let\@found\@empty
    \@for\@type:=\bmpsize@types\do{%
      \ifx\@found\@empty
        \@nameuse{bmpsize@read@\@type}{#2.\@type}%
        \ifbmpsize@ok
          \let\@found=\@type
        \fi
      \fi
    }%
    \ifx\@found\@empty\includegraphics[{#1}]{#2}%
    \else\includegraphics[{natwidth=\bmpsize@width,natheight=\bmpsize@height,#1}]{#2}%
    \fi}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \IncludeGraphics{lion.png} % a png image
  \IncludeGraphics{lion.gif} % a gif image
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for theq uick reply. Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't this the same as 'involves invoking ImageMagick on every compile, which will be unnecessarily slow & introduce a rather awkward dependency'?

Answer (score 3):

You could also manually add the `natwidth` and `natheight` properties to each image like:

```
\includegraphics[natwidth=800,natheight=600,width=\textwidth]{simple_ambiguity.png}
```

This should work with both `latex` and `pdflatex`.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't care about the size of the picture you can simply use the `demo`-option of the `graphicx` package:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{dontexist.png}

\end{document}
```

Or you can redefine `\includegraphics`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\renewcommand\includegraphics[2][]{\fbox{here graphic #2}}
\begin{document}

\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{dontexist.png}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks... but doesn't this mean I would have to comment/uncomment a line every time I switched from DVI target to PDF target?

Comment: Use the ifpdf package if you want a different behaviour depending on the output mode.