# LaTeX Error: Cannot determine size of graphic in title.png (no BoundingBox)

Tags: graphics, pdftex, miktex, png

I seem to be getting a strange error after updating MiKTeX 2.9. I am using pdfLaTeX and TeXmaker with the `graphicx` package to include `.png` images. When I try to compile, I get the error `LaTeX Error: File 'title' not found.` If I include the file extension, then the error becomes `LaTeX Error: Cannot determine size of graphic in title.png (no BoundingBox)`. I wasn't getting these errors a few days ago when I started creating my presentation. It has also worked without problems in the past.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{figures/}}
\begin{document}
    \title{title}
    \author{author}
    \date{date}
    \titlegraphic{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{title}}
    \frame{\titlepage}
\end{document}
```

Also, from the logfile it seems that pdfLaTeX is not in PDF mode, and that all graphics are being treated as `.eps`:

```
Package: ifpdf 2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
Package ifpdf Info: pdfTeX in PDF mode is not detected.
...
File: title.png Graphic file (type eps)
```

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) The first problem is related to the second (and actual) problem. [`latex` cannot determine the natural dimensions of an image.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/94870/16595) So the real question is: Why is pdfLaTeX not in PDF mode? Does your MWE compile if you use `pdflatex` from the command line (`pdflatex <filename>`)? It seems as if your editor is set up to use `latex` rather than `pdflatex`.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel I get the same error messages when using `pdflatex` from the command line. I checked the options in Texmaker, but it does look like it is set up to use `pdflatex`. The first line of the logfile also shows `This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (MiKTeX 2.9) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2013.2.18)  18 FEB 2013 16:52`

Comment: That usually means that TeX isn't able to process the image, either because the image's format isn't supported or just the image isn't found.

Comment: Could it be that you have several files with basename `title`, that some of them have a `pdf` or an `eps` extension and that they're corrupt? If yes, a possible solution may be adding the extension to the filename `title`.

Comment: @vonbrand I was able to get my presentation to compile with images included a few days ago, so perhaps it's something to do with updating MiKTeX. I will try on a different computer at home without updating to see if the problem persists.

Comment: @MarcvanDongen, you could be right. Or some wrong setup for imageformats. Try leaving _only_ the "right" format images around. Clean the temporary files, and re-run LaTeX.

Comment: @MarcvanDongen @vonbrand In my figures subdirectory I have a total of 7 `png` images (no other formats). I can open the images to view so they don't appear to be corrupt. I also tried removing all files except the `tex` source and images, but the error persists.

Comment: @m0nk3y: There was an update some days ago (12.2.) which broke the formats. The error has been corrected but perhaps you still have remains. Run the update manager (admin + user mode). Recreate all formats. If the problem persist you will have to find the local ini-files and correct them manually. If you are in a hurry: you can also put `\pdfoutput=1` at the start of your document, this will switch the mode back to pdf.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I have the same problem with the PNGs despite updating to the current version. Thanks for the \pdfoutput=1 trick, though. It works well for the time being!

Comment: @hjschulz: Updating is not enough. You should also recreate the formats (as user). If this doesn't help: Rename in the UserData and (perhaps) CommonData-root (*not* in the main root!) in the folder `miktex/config`  `formats.ini`, `language.ini` and if it exists `pdflatex.ini`. And then recreate the formats again. (This can change the language and format settings, you can reset them in miktex->settings).

Comment: I tried compiling my document at home and it worked, both before and after updating MiKTeX. So it looks like something has gone wrong with this installation as @UlrikeFischer suggested. I also tried adding `\pdfoutput=1` after `\documentclass{beamer}`, but the error persists. @UlrikeFischer- I tried renaming `formats.ini`, `languages.ini` and `pdflatex.ini` in the installation directory and then updating formats, but I just received error messages so I changed the filenames back to the originals. Is there anything else I can try apart from reinstalling MiKTeX?

Comment: @m0nk3y: I explicitly wrote that you should not change files in the main root (=installation root). Go to miktex-setting, tab "root", activate "show miktex roots", it will show you the path to UserConfig (not UserData as I wrote by mistake in the previous comment). There you will find the local ini's.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: I opened MiKTeX settings as user and checked "show MiKTeX roots". I then looked in the locations specified as "UserConfig", "UserData" and "CommonConfig", but none of those locations (in `miktex/config`) contained the `ini` files. So I tried going to `CommonConfig/miktex/data/le/pdftex`, renamed `pdflatex.fmt` and `pdftex.fmt`, and then recreated formats. This then allowed me to compile without errors. If you post an answer, I will accept it. Thanks for your help and patience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem was solved by renaming `pdflatex.fmt` and `pdftex.fmt` in the `CommonConfig/miktex/data/le/pdftex` directory and then recreating formats as "user".