# Is there anything wrong including this png?

Tags: graphics, png

I'm writing a document (article class), and I'm including some png graphics, this is the code that includes them (it's a subimage environment):

```
\begin{center}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
                \includegraphics[natwidth=512px,natheight=511px,width=4cm,height=4cm]{param.png}
                \caption{img1}
                \label{img1}
        \end{subfigure}%
        ~ %add desired spacing between images, e. g. ~, \quad, \qquad, \hfill etc.
          %(or a blank line to force the subfigure onto a new line)
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
                \includegraphics[natwidth=512px,natheight=511px,width=4cm,height=4cm]{crtpnt.png}
                \caption{img2}
                \label{fig:img2}
        \end{subfigure}
        ~ %add desired spacing between images, e. g. ~, \quad, \qquad, \hfill etc.
          %(or a blank line to force the subfigure onto a new line)
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
                \includegraphics[natwidth=512px,natheight=511px,width=4cm,height=4cm]{ferro.png}
                \caption{img3}
                \label{fig:img3}
        \end{subfigure}
\caption[prueba]{\label{fig:images}caption}\end{figure}\end{center}
```

I'm compiling through `latex` and then `dvipdf` to get a pdf. Firt of all, if I compile with pdflatex it works perfectly, but I would like to compile with an intermediate dvi file. When running Latex the dvi file is alright, although images don't show up. If I run then the dvipdf, it cuts the document up to the page in which the previous snippet is, not showing the images, or anything else beyond them.

I have previous images in eps format which are perfectly included. Is the way I'm including png graphics right? Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Nope, it's not right. You **can't** use `.png` files with `latex`. The `pdflatex` runs were successfull, as you wrote. Either use the `.eps` version or `pdflatex`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Ok, I will just transform them all to eps format. I was reading some questions like http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94869/error-including-a-png-cannot-determine-size-of-graphic aand it was said that latex just needed to know the natural size of the image... So I thought I could use png images

Comment: If you can directly generate the `.eps` files it would be much better than using a pixel format such as png

Comment: I just used ImageMagick, I did `convert file.png file.eps` and it worked perfectly. They're very simple images graphically, so I guess any problem I could have producing vector images dissappears.

Comment: unrelated but the `\begin{center}` outside the figure is wrong, it doesn't affect the alignment, just adds spurious vertical space. Also ` ~ ` is a slightly odd way to specify a space of three word spaces, and it relies on 6 word spaces being less than .1\textwidth.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Oh god thank you so much, I didn't know where the hell that odd vertical space was coming from... :)

Comment: `pdflatex` will read PNG files natively, and I've never needed a `natwidth` or `natheight` parameter for `\includegraphics`. `height` and/or `width`, sure, all the time. Modern TeX distributions can automatically convert EPS graphics to PDF for use with `pdflatex` as well, with no additional packages added to your document.