# Sporadic Error - LaTeX Error: Cannot determine size of graphic in png (no BoundingBox)

Tags: graphics

I'm using Overleaf to work on a project and just started receiving this error on all of my images. As a result, when I compile, the PDF will stop at the bottom of the last page before the first image appears.

I haven't touched the project or the code in about a month and had no errors before or problems compiling the document.

The code for my images is relatively simple:

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.6\columnwidth]{why_multiple_choice.png}
    \caption{some caption}
    \label{fig:why_multiple_choice_chart}
\end{figure}
```

I've tried jpg, png, and pdf. No difference.

Strangely, I can export my project and upload it as a new project to Overleaf and it compiles just fine... so strange! Because of the history on this project, I'd love to resolve the issue rather than switch over.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot determine size of graphic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17734/cannot-determine-size-of-graphic) and [MikTex error for PNG images when trying to produce DVI](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11193/miktex-error-for-png-images-when-trying-to-produce-dvi)

Comment: switching between png and pdf should make a difference. latex can not include pdf and pdflatex can not include png. The error suggests you are using png file but processing with latex not pdflatex