# Which DVI viewer on linux?

Tags: viewers, linux, dvi

Today, to my complete disbelief, I realized `evince` on Gnome 3 is not able to open DVI files. Which readers do you suggest, and why? It would prefer gnome applications of course, but I don't mind KDE/Qt either.

*update:* I'm on Fedora with TeX Live 2011.

Comment: On Fedora you need to install the separate package `evince-dvi` to enable DVI support.

Comment: @Martin: see my reply in Jasper's answer. TeX Live causes some problems with that.

Comment: Are you really sure that you want DVI? See [Is there any reason to compile to DVI rather than PDF these days?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2811/is-there-any-reason-to-compile-to-dvi-rather-than-pdf-these-days)

Comment: @Marco: unfortunately yes, I do. A package I need uses pstricks.

Comment: @JasperLoy: I did, but there's another issue there. It's OT here, but basically the output shown in xdvi has the correct page size, while on the other hand the converted pdf cuts the right margin.

Comment: @Riccardo: Since page size seems to be the actual problem you want to solve, why not ask a question about that?

Comment: @Caramdir: I'll surely do it, but not now because I don't have time to write it properly :)

Comment: @Caramdir: I wrote my problem in another question, here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54749/trouble-with-latex-and-dvips-with-an-fsttcs-documentclass

Answer (score 12, accepted):

By default, one needs to install the basic TeX packages from the Ubuntu repositories to view DVI files with `Evince` on Ubuntu. Similarly, one needs to install `evince-dvi` from the Fedora repositories to view DVI files with `Evince` on Fedora.

If you are using TeX Live installed directly from TUG, you may also use the `xdvi` provided.

Comment: I'm using TeX Live, aren't there any other options apart from xdvi, please?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't: there's a conflict arising from the `kpathsea-2007-66.fc16` package, which is required by `evince-dvi` and made obsolete by the latest one from TeX Live.

Comment: What's wrong with xdvi?  I find it quick and easy to use. (Not that I use .dvi much anymore....)

Answer (score 5):

`okular`, the default and universal KDE viewer supports DVI files very well (at least as far as I remember, because I rarely work with DVI files for some time now).

Answer (score 3):

If you're running the 64bit version of Fedora, you can download modified *evince* packages here:
http://mgieseki.fedorapeople.org/evince/

*evince-dvi* is built against the latest kpathsea package from Jindrich Novy's TeX Live 2011 repository. Thus, installing the dvi evince extension works properly together with TeX Live 2011.

Answer (score 1):

TeX Live from Ubuntu/Debian and that from TUG have different directory structures. In both cases xdvi work fine because they are configured correspondingly.
xReader, Evince, and Okular work fine with TeX Live from Ubuntu/Debian and do not with TUG TeX Live.
Atril is configured to work with TUG TeX Live.