# Trouble with latex and dvips with an FSTTCS documentclass

Tags: pdftex, margins, document-classes, dvips

Following from my other question [Which DVI viewer on linux?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54403/which-dvi-viewer-on-linux), now that I can easily view DVI files I came to the conclusion that the unusual document class I used for my document defines some non-standard margins and/or page size.
This clashes with my compilation chain `latex --> dvips --> ps2pdf` (I'm using PSTricks): the dvi file looks formatted fine, but `dvips` isn't able to get the page size right and the margins look shifted.

The class file I'm using is located [here](http://www.fsttcs.org/fsttcs.cls) (in the *submission format* section of the [FSTTCS conference page](http://www.fsttcs.org/cfp.php) there is also a zip file with a readme and examples). You can see my problem by compiling this minimal example:

```
\documentclass{fsttcs}
\begin{document}
\title{My document}
\runningtitle{My document}
\runningauthors{A, B, C}
\author{A, B, C}
\affiliation{XYZ}
\section{Sect. 1}
This is the section 1 of the test file.
This is the section 1 of the test file.
This is the section 1 of the test file.
\newpage
\section{Sect. 2}
This is the section 2 of the test file.
This is the section 2 of the test file.
This is the section 2 of the test file.
\newpage
\section{Sect. 3}
This is the section 3 of the test file.
This is the section 3 of the test file.
This is the section 3 of the test file.
\end{document}
```

With a simple `pdflatex test.tex` everything looks ok, but when I run `latex test.tex && dvips test.dvi && ps2pdf test.ps`, the page slightly changes its proportions and the page contents are shifted.
I tried passing specifying all formats supported by `dvips` (letter, legal, ledger, a4, a3) with the `dvips -t <size>`, but none of them works correctly.

I'm sure `pdflatex` gives the correct output because it is the same as the precompiled pdf included in the example zip file, but I can't use it because of PSTricks and I'm unable to specify the correct format to `dvips`. What should I do, please?

Comment: It's quite obscure why the class sets `letterpaper` but then calls `crop` with the `a4` option. However, you get identical results by adding the option `a4paper` or `letterpaper` to `\documentclass`. The provided example uses ISO A4 paper.

Comment: @egreg: hi, thanks for passing by. I think it may have something to do with the page numbers: the body with the contents is always centered, but the page numbers appears to its right and its left side (see my example compiled wit `pdflatex`). Unfortunately both the options you suggest lead to results different from the correct one.

Comment: it is possible to use `pdflatex` when using `PSTricks`- see these questions [http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=pdflatex+pstricks](http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=pdflatex+pstricks) for details

Comment: `dvi2pdf` directly works OK for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I get the same result as the examples provided by stating explicitly that we want A4 paper:

```
\documentclass{fsttcs}
\usepackage{ifpdf}
\ifpdf\else
  \AtBeginDvi{\special{papersize=21cm,29.7cm}}
\fi
\begin{document}
```

However the class is badly written, as it uses `geometry` but sets `\paperwidth` and `\paperheight` in incompatible ways. It's not clear what page dimensions they would like: the class issues `letterpaper`, but then also uses the `a4` option to `crop` and defines even different sizes afterwards.

Comment: That's great, it works like a charm... thanks a lot!