# How to set page display in pdflatex?

Tags: hyperref, pdftex, viewers

I've never used LaTeX before, but a few months ago I decided to write my thesis report in LaTeX, so I'm pretty new to it.

I am using MiKTeX on Windows 7, and `pdflatex` as typesetting engine. The thing that is bugging me is that `pdflatex` flips page when scrolling. I would *really* like to have it continuously "flipped" i.e. scrolling down the document as one whole column. I've searched the web and this forum without finding a solution (of course I've looked in `pdflatex` as well). Maybe I'm just missing out some simple preferences in `pdflatex` page somewhere?

I can fix this for preview in my regular PDF viewer (Adobe Reader) by using the `hyperref` package and `\hypersetup` command, like this:

```
\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
  pdfpagelayout={OneColumn}}
```

Unfortunately this doesn't help me since it's `pdflatex` I'm using to quickly see the outcome of the code and I'm typesetting pretty often. Perhaps there's a better PDF previewer that is as fast and simple as `pdflatex`?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) It's not possible to have the document shown as a continuous scroll; the typesetting engine splits it into pages, because that's how you will have your document. Moreover, the engine is limited as far as lengths are concerned; you can get one scroll for some (actually several) pages, but the maximum length is about 6 meters.

Comment: If I understand your inquiry correctly, you're looking to change the settings on your pdf viewer so that the display scrolls smoothly from page to page rather than jumping discretely. This is a setting governed by the pdf viewer you use. In Adobe Acrobat (and Adobe Reader as well, in all likelihood), you'd go to "View" -> "Page Display" and then click on "Enable Scrolling". The appropriate commands for other pdf viewers will differ, of course. Incidentally, `pdflatex` is *not* a pdf previewer, but only the program that generates the pdf file.

Comment: Just to add to Mico's "pdflatex is not a pdf previewer, its an engine to generate pdf". you can read the more [tug.org](http://www.tug.org/levels.html)

Comment: @egreg: I thought that since Adobe Reader can show the document with smooth scrolling, so could the TeXworks previewer (or any pdf viewer).

Comment: @Mico: That's exactly what I've done in Adobe Reader, so I'm looking for a previewer that can do that, that will pop-up like the TeXworks previewer, when I click "Typeset"....

Comment: @LarsBjörnsson Sorry for having misunderstood your question. But you didn't mention TeXworks, which is a rather basic front-end to the TeX system, and its PDF previewer has a very minimal set of features (the whole design of TeXworks is minimalistic, one should say). You can look at TeXStudio instead: http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @egreg: I realize that I mislead some of you, since I was obviously confused myself with the actual names of the stuff :)   The minimalistic design of Texworks compiler-viewer solution suits my way of working very well, since I like to look at the results while I'm typing.

Comment: @LarsBjörnsson Another Alternative is [Texmaker 3.5.2](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you use TeXworks editor, which really shows pages `SinglePage` whatever you do. It is the property of its PDF preview and it cannot be changed.

The `pdfpagelayout` setting is aimed mostly on Acrobat (Reader).

Comment: I realize I confused pdflatex with the TeXworks pdf previewer, thanks for pointing that out! However, it seems like you understood what I asked for.

Comment: And the question is consequently if there is any previewer that can scroll pages smoothly? Except adobe reader, since that's not a very fast way of updating...

Comment: @LarsBjörnsson See this question: [Output viewers for use with LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2006/11002)

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be the thread for further investigation!

Comment: @LarsBjörnsson Since your issue seems to be solved, please consider marking the answer as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This way, other people know that their effort here is not needed anymore.