# Adobe Reader or Adobe Acrobat

Tags: pdf, viewers

I would like to know, if I can use LaTeX to generate report if I only have Adobe Reader or do I need Adobe Acrobat as well?

Comment: You won't get anywhere here if you don't invest some time in learning something about LaTeX. If you tell us your country, maybe readers here can give you advise where to find manuals etc. in your language. Besides that: you don't need neither Adobe Reader nor Adobe Acrobat to generate PDF using LaTeX.

Comment: Neither of those two applications has _anything_ to do with LaTeX. Hence, the answer is simple, you do not need either of the applications.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: Have a look at Answers to [Best Way to Start Using LaTeX/TeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4420/15717). Follow stepwise procedure at http://www.ctan.org/starter.html. You would need Acrobat Reader to view the generated `.pdf` from LaTeX.

Comment: Ok, but doesn't LaTeX create things in a pdf format? Don't I neccessarily need Adobe Reader to view that at the end? Tkank you for all the info.

Comment: The PDF format is open and there are many viewers for all operating systems.

Comment: Why is the OP being bashed about not knowing something here?

Comment: @texenthusiast: He doesn't need any Adobe application; just a PDF viewer (of which there are many).

Comment: @percusse: "This question does not show any research effort"?

Comment: @MartinSchröder It's a well-known beginner confusion. I had the same problem for a long time. Especially if you are not into academia it's not that easy to get the basics as everything is named ....TeX.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Adobe Acrobat is the full suite for creating/manipulating PDF documents. Adobe Reader is the less powerful but more convenient display version with limited document manipulation features. However Adobe Acrobat is not the only way to create PDF files. As long as the result is PDF-standard-compatible, the creator of the PDF document is not relevant.

The (La)TeX input file is a plain text file. If you compile this input file with `pdflatex`, you will get a PDF output. There are some PDF viewers you can use to view this PDF output. Adobe Reader is a free one and it is enough.

But if you compile the input file with `latex`, you will get a DVI output. In this decade, I don't think you want to have a DVI output. And if  you convert the DVI output with `dvips`, you will get a PS output. It is also uncommon to have a PS output. To convert the PS output to PDF, use `ps2pdf` converter. Now you get a PDF output.

You might be confused with either using  a single `pdflatex` or `latex-dvips-ps2pdf`. The rule of thumb is use `pdflatex` if your input file imports PDF, PNG, JPG images and has no PSTricks code. Use `latex-dvips-ps2pdf` if your input file import EPS images and has PSTricks code.

Comment: [Sumatra PDF](http://blog.kowalczyk.info/software/sumatrapdf/free-pdf-reader.html) is good alternative to acrobat reader, it's also free pdf reader for Windows. For more [Output viewers for use with LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2006/15717)

Comment: There's also still `dvipdfmx`; no need to generate PostScript.