# What's the difference between align and align*?

Tags: amsmath, align, starred-version

After some brief searching I can't find the difference between `align` and `align*`. Google summarily ignoring the * is making it harder I think.

Can you tell me the difference between these two?

Moreover, can you tell me where you generally go for this type of information? As a relatively new user I'm still building up my resources.

Comment: Have a look at: [What are other good resources on-line for information about TeX, LaTeX and friends?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/162/what-are-other-good-resources-on-line-for-information-about-tex-latex-and-friend)

Comment: [Herbert Voß' "mathmode"](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/voss-mathmode.html) is very useful for math typesetting problems.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The star at the end of the name  of a displayed math environment causes that the formula lines won't be numbered. Otherwise they would automatically get a number.

You can read about that in the [amsmath user's guide](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/amsmath/amsmath.pdf) since `align` belongs to amsmath.

Such information can usually be found in the package documentation. Type `texdoc packagename` at the command prompt or visit http://ctan.org/pkg/packagename. If you use google or another search engine, look for *starred* and *commandname*.

Commonly, a star symbol `*` means a version of a command that behaves differently from the original. That often means suppressing numbering but could also refer to special features. For example, have a look at [What's the difference between `\newcommand` and `\newcommand*`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1050/whats-the-difference-between-newcommand-and-newcommand)

Answer (score 7):

> "One could take a look in the manual
>   out of sheer desperation." (based on
>   Herbert Voß)

Googling should have told you that `align` and `align*` are part of the amsmath package. Page 3 of its [documentation](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/required/amslatex/math/amsldoc.pdf) reveals:

> The amsmath package provides a number
>   of additional displayed equation
>   structures beyond the ones provided in
>   basic LaTeX. The augmented set
>   includes:
>
> [...] `align` `align*` [...]
>
> Except for `split`, each environment has
>   both starred and unstarred forms,
>   where the unstarred forms have
>   automatic numbering using LaTeX’s
>   `equation` counter.

You could also simply try out what the difference might be:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
a_1& =b_1+c_1\\
a_2& =b_2+c_2-d_2+e_2
\end{align}

\begin{align*}
a_1& =b_1+c_1\\
a_2& =b_2+c_2-d_2+e_2
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```