# what does an asterisk (*) character do in a renewcommand?

Tags: macros, syntax, starred-version

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the difference between \newcommand and \newcommand*?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1050/whats-the-difference-between-newcommand-and-newcommand)

I've seen `*` used in memoir.cls:

```
   \renewcommand*{\chapnumfont}{\normalfont\HUGE\sffamily}
```

and wondered which is the purpose of the `*` here?

Comment: See perhaps http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45393/meaning-of-in-a-macro-name

Comment: See also: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30456/do-all-starred-commands-have-anything-in-common