# What's difference between renewcommand and renewcommand*?

Tags: macros, koma-script

Example usage:

```
\documetclass{article}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand*{\captionformat}{ -- }
\renewcommand{\captionformat}{ -- }
\end{document}
```

Comment: The star version produces a command that is not "long", meaning that star-version newcommands cannot take arguments that contain a `\par`.  In your example, there is no difference, since `\captionformat` takes zero arguments.  If, for example, `\newcommand*{\captionformat}[1]{ -#1- }`, then `\captionformat{x\par x}` would produce an error.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes, thank you very much!

Comment: Side note for this command in particular you can find documentation in "the LaTeX unofficial reference manual"

Comment: (or [macros - what does an asterisk (*) character do in a renewcommand? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55793/what-does-an-asterisk-character-do-in-a-renewcommand?noredirect=1&lq=1) for one specific to **re**newcommand)