# Why do we use a star (*) after a command in LaTeX?

Tags: starred-version

I sometimes see some code snippets including star (*) with command such as `\hspace*{.5em}`, `\newcommand*{}`, `\chapter*{}`.

I wonder what the star is for in latex format when collaborating with a command?

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30456/do-all-starred-commands-have-anything-in-common, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45393/meaning-of-an-asterisk-in-a-macro-name

Comment: It has very different meanings depending on the command...

Comment: But one thing it has in common is that it is a variant of the unstarred version of the command.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes only by definition (or by convention depending on your point of view), the commands don't have to share any code or have any particular features in common.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Concur completely.  I meant it "by convention" rather than "by definition."