# How to hide the number of a table, whilst keeping it in the list of tables

Tags: tables, table-of-contents, captions

I want the caption of one of my tables to say only Table, without the number. Caption* did not seem to work.

Also, I still I want it to appear in the list of tables. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: `table*` is not for not numbering the caption.

Comment: You are right, I changed that to caption*

Comment: Actually, caption* does not do it. I will edit my question. Thank you

Comment: For some discussion on the use of `*` see: [Do all starred commands have anything in common?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30456)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Package `caption` provides a star form of `\caption` as in `longtable`, where the star form suppresses the numbering and the entry in the table of contents.

The entry for the list of tables can be added via `\addcontentsline{lot}{table}{...}`. Example, which also supports `hyperref`:

```
\documentclass{article}
% \usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{caption}% for star form: \caption*

\begin{document}
  \listoftables

  \section{My section}
  The beautiful table can be found on page \pageref{fig:my}.

 \begin{table}[hpb]
    \csname phantomsection\endcsname % anchor, if hyperref is loaded
    \centering
    \fbox{My beautiful table}
    \caption*{My table caption}
    \label{fig:my}
    \addcontentsline{lot}{table}{My table caption}
  \end{table}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: That seems ideal. However, with my template (using classicthesis.sty), it comes up as Table 0.1*: (new line) thecaption

Comment: @dorien That means, the star form is not recognized and the star is taken as caption title. Is package `caption` loaded?

Comment: Excellent! Is there also a way to output "Table: " in front?

Comment: @dorien "Table: " could be put inside the title and be omitted in the entry for the list of figures.

Comment: Very true! Only minor thing left: it does not appear  nice in the toc, because it is not indented. See here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13564139/toc.png

Comment: Mmmm maybe this is because I use a package for TOC (tocloft). Another option would be to set the table number to 1 for instance. Would that be possible somehow?

Comment: Ok, I just added this before. Solved now: \renewcommand\thetable{Blub 8.3-x}