# What is the difference between \begin{gather} and \begin{gather*}?

Tags: amsmath

I guess the asterisk has a general meaning at that position and probably should know it, but I just can't find it in amsmath manual.

Comment: The star versions of the amsmath environments are unnumberred.

Comment: I just noted that because my other question was answered, so that I could have \begin{gather} working and note that difference very obviously. Now I see why this question wasn't asked before...

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9514/whats-the-difference-between-align-and-align

Comment: Reading the manual helps ;-) `Except for split, each environment has both starred and unstarred forms,
where the unstarred forms have automatic numbering using LATEX's equation
counter.` (Section 3.1, 3rd. paragraph ;-))

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I had control-effed for "asterisk" and "gather", didn't realize that the word to be searched was "starred".

Comment: @LeonardoCastro: Admitted `starred` could be misleading, but `gather` yields the 2nd paragraph in the mentioned section and there's `gather*`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Fair enough, mea culpa. I had searched for gather* but seen that it appeared only once while I expected a sentence like "gather* is used for..." My vision field didn't reach the second paragraph of that section immediately, so I found easier to ask it here. Anyway, am I the only one who uses this site mainly to avoid reading documentation of all packages I use. :-) Is this site only for advanced questions?

Comment: @LeonardoCastro: No, but often reading the documentation clearifies the question before it is posted. However, there's documentation, that is not clear in all situations and some packages have hidden features not described anywhere. In this situation a 'non-advanced' question is fully justified. (And I am not one of the close voters ;-))