# I am a latex enthusiast, I am finding it very difficult to produce documents

Tags: learning

Can anyone help with producing documents with ease?

I am using Miktex and winEdt.

I am finding it difficult with the following
1. Setting margins
2. Getting poor spacing after paragraphs etc
3. Compiling(there would be some small stopping, I usually use 'h' for help, resolve it
if I can or I use 'r' for non stop compilation)

Comment: Which part of the production process do you find particularly un-easy?

Comment: Hi, welcome to TeX-SX!  To best help you, it would be useful to have more details about exactly what you are trying to do.  Try finding a minimal example and posting it here (see http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/86 )

Answer (score 10, accepted):

LaTeX can be very confusing at first.

### What do I need?

A decent editor can help ease the transition. [Texmaker](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/) has wizards for inputting commonly needed elements like tables, figures and mathematic symbols. Autocomplete function is quite useful for learning.

If you are looking for something more basic, [TeXworks](http://www.tug.org/texworks/) comes bundled with MikTeX. Autocomplete is available as well with <kbd>tab</kbd>.

### Where to start learning?

Take a look at the list of available online resources listed as an aswer to the [LaTeX online resources question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/162/what-are-other-good-resources-on-line-for-information-about-tex-latex-and-friend).

[LaTeX wikibook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX) has a very good balance between accessibility and usefulness.

### What next?

When you encounter a specific need or a problem, feel free to ask a question here. Be sure to include a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). Also see [how to write a MWE in more detail](http://www.minimalbeispiel.de/mini-en.html). Take a look at [our faq](https://tex.stackexchange.com/faq) for help in [writing good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Be sure to try and find the solution yourself at LaTeX wikibook first. You will be surprised how well its content matches the usual needs.

You might not get the entire solution, but be pointed to reading documentation for some package that will be useful for your need. LaTeX packages are usually well documented and will most likely have some samples for use included.

Comment: Also take a look at our Unofficial FAQ: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1144/the-unofficial-tex-sx-faq which is a little more site-specific.

Answer (score 1):

You should listen what prettygully and Andrew told you. Anyway I think that you need to read the documentation. Always keep with you a good guide (for example [The not so short introduction to LaTeX2e](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBUQFjAA&url=http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/lshort/english/lshort.pdf&ei=RhS5TayrAsrcsgau9oDrAw&usg=AFQjCNGlIFiqkZqWlimc_td_2FA38ZkhMQ)) in which there are answers for the most common problems.
1. For margin take a look at the `geometry` package
2. I don't know
3. You make some mistakes in writing the code, so listen what Andrew said and find a minimal example that gives the errors.

Answer (score 1):

For compiling, I've found [TeXlipse](http://texlipse.sourceforge.net/) to be really easy to use -- it shows the errors in the editor (same as when compiling Java programs), and the text completion functionality is convenient. It has some quirks, but I would definitely recommend it, especially if you have any experience with Eclipse.

TeXlipse is an Eclipse plugin, so you will need [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) to use it. If you already have Miktex, then it should work without too much configuration.