# LaTeX related jobs

Tags: collaboration

Well for the things in life, I've learned LaTeX. I'm not a guru, but I think that I can perform some good quality documents. I want to know if is possible to get a part-time job in an editorial, journal or something like that. I'm outside of the U. S., but I think that perhaps is possible to work by Internet.

Comment: Please retag the question properly. This is my first post here, I can't create new tags. Thanks.

Comment: Of course it is possible, you just have to find it. It'll help if you build up a reputation on this site beforehand so people can know that you are knowledgeable. That being said, I am not sure that this is an appropriate form for this forum.

Comment: @PeterGrill: thanks. Yes, I ask this here thinking that this post could be closed.

Comment: @leo I agree this is really off-topic for the site, so have closed the question.

Comment: There are so few jobs that pay specifically for TeX skills because, after all, that would constitute and Income TeX (ba-da-boom).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, this is probably not an appropriate forum for this kind of question. However, if someone comes across this might be a useful link: [Where can I find people for hire with LaTeX skills and designer skills?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19553/where-to-find-people-for-hire-with-latex-skills-and-designer-skills)